# creating a javascript function to reverse a word

Tags: javascript, reverse

Hi am trying to create a javascript function to reverse a word, but it seems the for loop is not begin executed and the holder variable is not being append in the for loop.

```
function jump(str){
    var holder ="";
    var len = str.length-1;
    for(var i =len; i == 0; i--){
        holder += str[i];
    }
    return holder;
}
console.log(jump("Just do it!"))
```

Comment: `"Just do it!".split("").reverse().join("")`

Comment: alternative: str.split('').reverse().join(''), because strings doesn't have reverse backed in, but arrays do.

Comment: Change `==` to `>=`. Also, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958908/how-do-you-reverse-a-string-in-place-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var result = str.split("").reverse().join("");
```

Answer (score 4):

Your loop is incorrect:

```
for(var i =len; i == 0; i--){
                  ^^^
```

The loop body only fires if that middle condition is "true". On its first iteration, `i` is something like `10`, which means `10 == 0` is **NOT** true, aka false.

You probably want

```
for(var i =len; i >= 0; i--){
```

instead.

Comment: Actually, it would be `>=`

Answer (score 3):

I think this should work for you

```
var text = 'Just do it!';
var rev = text.split("").reverse().join("").split(" ").reverse().join(" ");
```

Comment: This outputs `it! do Just`

Comment: @jperezov Improved it, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

The loop

```
for(var i =len; i == 0; i--){
    holder += str[i];
}
```

will only run when i is equal to zero - which won't be the case, since you set it up as the length of your (presumably) populated string. Try:

```
for(var i =len; i >= 0; i--){
    holder += str[i];
}
```

Comment: As per the question, this is the best answer.  And that one character really was the whole problem.

Comment: how do i reverse a sentence like Hello World to World Hello

Comment: Thats a bit more complicated and not in the scope of the original question. Off the top of my head, I'd say split the string into an array of words by splitting using spaces, then run your reversal code from above but on the array elements and not single characters