# How to return varchar input in reverse by using funtion

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper

I have a interview question to write a function which takes input as varchar and the output should give in reverse order of input.

This is the code I wrote

`

```
SQL> create or replace function fn( id in varchar2) return varchar2 is 
2  input varchar2(25) := id;
3
4  begin
5
6  dbms_output.put_line(reverse(input));
7
8  return input;
9
10  end;
11  /

Warning: Function created with compilation errors.

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- ------------------------------------------------------------
6/1      PL/SQL: Statement ignored
6/22     PLS-00201: identifier 'REVERSE' must be declared
SQL> select reverse(ename) from emp;
`
```

Help me with this

Reverse keyword working in SQL where in PLSQL doesn't. why?

Comment: Use plv8 to run this Javascript function: http://stackoverflow.com/a/959004/2259571

Comment: I need to write a plsql code not javascript and I don't about javascript

Comment: It's similar to the above but it is function and that is procedure, Thank you for your reply now I know how to write the same program using Procedures to.

Comment: REVERSE function has to be used with SELECT statement only as per oracle.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

I got the answer now, but I want to know is this perfect answer or is there any other I can do this?

Comment: If you want reviews of working code, you want [codereview.se]. Make sure you understand their guidelines. But... It sounds like you haven't submitted this for the interview yet. Having other people review it would not be a reflection of *your* skills, now would it?

Comment: Why to use cursor and open fetch??? It can be simply a SELECT INTO statement and RETURN the output in the function.