# Inline input to custom function

Tags: javascript

I like to implement reverse() method on string.
But input should be inline. such as,

```
"December".reverse();

function reverse(){
    return reverse("").join(" ");
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/958908/how-do-you-reverse-a-string-in-place-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ?

```
String.prototype.reverse = function() {
  return this.split("").reverse().join("");
}

"test".reverse() // tset
```

Don't forget to define the propotype before use it