# How to reverse a word with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'd like to reverse a word in a string with javascript, I wrote this code but it isn't working and I can't figure it out why.
I want to write a word in a box and when I press the button has to appear the same word but reversed. For example, If I write "hello" in the textbox then it has to appear "olleh".

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="it"> 
<head> 
<meta charset="utf-8"> 
<title>Reverse</title>
</head> 
<body> 
<input type="text" id="primo"><br>
<button type="button" onclick="rev()"> Reverse </button> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function rev(){
var string = document.getElementById("primo");
ciao = string.reverse();
document.write(ciao);
}
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: your variable `string` is an element...not a string

Comment: You're outputting the string `"ciao"` - when you want the variable. `document.write(ciao);`

Comment: @charlietfl how can I solve the problem?

Comment: Please do a web search ... there is no built in method for reversing strings but there are solutions all over the web

Comment: @tymeJV You're right, I corrected it but it doesn't working

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/958908/how-do-you-reverse-a-string-in-place-in-javascript

Comment: @GSazheniuk can you make an answer with my code please, I can't understand how to do it

Comment: @Gianni as it is stated in first answer, you should first split your string into characters' array, reverse array, and finally join it back to the string:
ciao = string.split("").reverse().join("");

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
String.prototype.reverse = function() {
  return this.split('').reverse().join('');
};

function rev() {
  var field = document.getElementById('primo');
  var ciao = field.value.reverse();
  document.body.insertAdjacentText('beforeend', ciao);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="primo"><br>
<button type="button" onclick="rev()">Reverse</button>
```