# How to do a reverse-word function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reverse

I'm trying to do a reverse-word script in javascript. I have written this function, but it does not work and I can't understand why. What is wrong? Is there any other way to do it?

```js
function inverser(x)
{
    var newString ="";
    var index=(x.length - 1);
    var y=0;
    
    for (var i=index ; i>=0 ; i--)
    {
        x[i] = newString [y++];
    }
    
    return (newString );
}

console.log(inverser("test"));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you reverse a string in place in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/958908/how-do-you-reverse-a-string-in-place-in-javascript)

Comment: logic is totally backwards

Comment: Your assignment is in reverse. And strings are immutable, you cannot assign to their indices at all. Use an array instead, or build the string through concatenation.

Comment: "but it does not work" isn't a very helpful description of your problem. What *is* the output for a given input? And what have you done to debug it?

Comment: It should be: `newString [y++] = x[i];` not `x[i] = newString [y++];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add to concatenate `newString` instead of trying to assign an index to it. The logic of your function should be

```
newString[y++] += x[i];
```

[Link to code](http://jsbin.com/zulohiz/edit?js,console)

Answer (score 0):

Use `reverse()`:

```
function inverser(x)
{   
    return x.split("").reverse().join("");
}
```

It's simple if you don't need build in function, please comment, i will update my answer :)

**Update**

> The assignment statements are wrong in your code, it should have been:

```
newString += x[i];
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I know that function, but I want to understand why my code does not work

Comment: Your assignment statement is wrong @PNB, I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

when you use newString[y++], newString is still empty string and doesn't have cell 1 or 2 or 3 .... and can't assign string to this cell.

simply if you remove y variable and make some move on line 9 can get answer.

here the code worked for me:

```
function inverser(x) {
  var newString = "";
  var index = (x.length - 1);

  for (var i = index; i >= 0; i--)
  {
    newString += x[i];
  }

  return (newString);
}
```