# Can anybody refactor this function that takes a number as an argument and reverses its digits?

Tags: javascript, function

Given a number, write a function to output its reverse digits. (e.g. given 123 the answer is 321)

Numbers should preserve their sign; i.e. a negative number should still be negative when reversed.

This was my solution:

```
function reverseNumber(n) {
  var split = (""+n).split("");
  var reverse = split.reverse();
  var last = reverse.join('');
  if(reverse[reverse.length - 1] == '-') {
    var almost = reverse.pop();
    var close = reverse.unshift(almost);
    var last2 = reverse.join('');
    var rev = Number(last2);
    return rev;
  } else {
    var pos = Number(last);
    return pos;
  }
}
```

It's too long. I'm wondering if anybody can come up with a shorter solution.

Comment: are you trying to reverse digits of a number (integer or float) and output a string?

Comment: are you only handling integers? or float as well ? -12.34 yields -43.21?

Comment: only integers, no floats

Comment: the output should be a number, not a string

Comment: `return Math.sign(n) * +Math.abs(n).toString().split("").reverse().join("");`, what kata is this?

Comment: Nice, never seen Math.sign() before, the kata is called [Reverse a number](https://www.codewars.com/kata/555bfd6f9f9f52680f0000c5)

Comment: So if the input is 100 the output should be 1 (and not the string "001")?

Comment: @ASDFGerte—the `+` before *Math* is redundant. ;-)

Comment: @RobG true :) seems like i am still not completely thinking in javascript's implicit conversions, here from the multiplication operator. I wonder if that is a good or a bad thing...

Comment: @ASDFGerte—I think it's a good thing given the primary use of javascript in a DOM means it should be tolerant of types as much as possible. That may not be best for other cases, but perhaps other languages should be used in those cases.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var numRev2 = function(n) {
  return n >= 0
      ? n.toString().split('').reverse().join('')
      : '-' + n.toString().substring(1).split('').reverse().join('');
}
//ES6
var numRev = n =>
    n > 0   ? n.toString().split('').reverse().join('')
            : '-' + n.toString().substring(1).split('').reverse().join('');

console.log ( numRev(743823) );
console.log ( numRev(-743823) );

console.log ( numRev2(743823) );
console.log ( numRev2(-743823) );
```

Comment: The "else" part can be `'-' + (-n + '').split('').reverse().join('');`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.reduceRight()`, `.join()`, `+` operator

```
+((...props) => props.reduceRight((a, b) => a.concat(b), []))(1,2,3).join("")
```

Comment: *"Given a number"* - but "1,2,3" is not a number... And given that `props` is an array, that `.reduceRight()` can be replaced by `.reverse()`.

Comment: @nnnnnn `1,2,3` is one way to pass N parameters or `123`. The pattern can also be composed to accept an array. Yes, `.reverse()` can also be utilized.

Comment: @nnnnnn `let n1 = 123;

let n2 = [4,5,6];

let rev = N => +((...props) => (props.length === 1 && typeof props[0] === "number" 
   ? [...String(props.pop())] : props.pop())
  .reduceRight((a, b) => a.concat(b), []))(N).join("");
  
console.log(rev(n1), rev(n2));`

Answer (score 0):

Some useful information is available at [*How do you reverse a string in place in JavaScript?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958908/how-do-you-reverse-a-string-in-place-in-javascript/16776621#16776621)

Since this has devolved to code golf, another answer won't hurt.

```js
function revNum(n) {
  return (n<0? -1 : 1) * ('' + Math.abs(n)).split('').reverse().join('');
}

[-12.3, 345.23, -0.765, 1.23e5].forEach(n=>console.log(n + ' : ' + revNum(n)));
```