# Reverse a string in javascript without using any inbuilt function

Tags: javascript

```
 function reverse1(str){
  var a = "";
  for(var i = 0; i <= str.length/2; i++){
    a = str[i];
    str[i] = str[str.length-i-1];
    str[str.length-i-1] = a;
  }
  return str;
}
var str = "abcdef";
reverse1(str);
```

I want to reverse a string without using any inbuilt function, and I want it to change the original string itself but it doesn't work well.
The language is Javascript.

Comment: You can't change original string. Strings are immutable

Comment: Strings in Javascript are immutable, so you can't modify the original string

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you reverse a string in place in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958908/how-do-you-reverse-a-string-in-place-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new string and add all the chars from the original string to it backwards:

```
function reverse1(str){
  var r = "";
  for(var i = str.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
    r += str.charAt(i);
  }
  return r;
}
```

Then just say:

```
str = reverse1(str);
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is the simplest way to do without using any javascript inbuilt function.

```js
function reverse1(str){
  let r = "";
  for(let i = str.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
    r += str[i];
  }
  return r;
}

console.log(reverse1("javascript"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Reverse the `forloop` iteration From high to low `i--` used to decrement the value of i

```js
function reverse1(str) {
str = str.trim();
var res ="";
   for(var i = str.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
      res +=str[i];
  }
  return res;
}
var str = "abcdef";
console.log(reverse1(str))
```

Comment: OP said "without using any inbuild function"

Comment: Not only did OP specifically ask for no built-in functions but also that the original string should be modified, which is impossible. The only proper answer to this question is "What you're asking for is not possible in Javascript"

Answer (score 0):

Javascript strings are [immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51185/are-javascript-strings-immutable-do-i-need-a-string-builder-in-javascript), you cannot simply replace a character with another one

```js
function reverse1(str){
  var  len = str.length, result = "";
  for(var i = 0; i <= len-1; i++){
    result = result + str[len-i-1];
  }
  return result;
}
var str = "abcdef";
str = reverse1(str);
console.log(str);
```

You can always create a new string and return it though

Answer (score 0):

Well if you don't want to use the inbuilt functions here you go

```
var string = 'hello';
function reverse(str) {
  if(!str.trim() || 'string' !== typeof str) {
    return;
  }
  var length=str.length;
  s='';
  while(length > 0) {
    length--;
    s+= str[l];
  }
  return s;
}

console.log(reverse(string));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const reverseString = (str = null) => {
let newStr = [];
let string = "";
let reverseStr = "";
for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
   if (str[i] == " ") {
       newStr.push(string);
       string = "";
   } else {
       string += str[i];
   }
 }
if (string) {  
newStr.push(string);
} 
for (i = newStr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
     reverseStr += newStr[i] + " ";
}
return reverseStr;
};
let val = reverseString("My name is mohd jagir");
console.log(val);
//output will be jagir mohd is name My
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using below way is simple and clean.

function reverse(str) {

```
return str.split("").reduce((a,b)=> a = b + a ,"")
```

}

Comment: The OP asked for a solution `without using any inbuilt function`, so this does not seem to be an answer to his question.

Answer (score -1):

i think this will be easy way to implement without using any inbuild function,you can reverse string also if you uncomment the commented code

```
const restring = "abcdf ghj";

// console.log(restring.length)
let temp = "";
// let valSplit = restring.split(" ");

for(let i = restring.length-1;i >= 0;i--){
    temp += (restring[i]) ;
}
console.log(temp)
```

Comment: This is quite an old question and your answer is the same as some of the already existing answers

Answer (score -4):

I think this question better answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431094/how-do-i-replace-a-character-at-a-particular-index-in-javascript). why char can't be change in a position.

[Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958908/how-do-you-reverse-a-string-in-place-in-javascript)

```js
function reverse(s){
    return s.split("").reverse().join("");
}
var originalString = "ABCD";
console.log(reverse(originalString));
console.log(originalString);
originalString = reverse(originalString);
console.log(originalString);
```

Comment: Have you read the question? " want to reverse a string without using **any inbuild function**"

Comment: For some reason, the OP doesn't want to use built-in methods.

Comment: I think this question should be why I  can't change the character of an array in a certain position.

Comment: Regardless of what you want the question to be, that isn't what the OP asked.  OP explicitly said no built-in functions.

Comment: Just trying to help with right way. There is already answered question about this.