# Why Javascript console.log result is undefined while reversing the string?

Tags: javascript, string, undefined, repeat

```
 var a = "gsdgtrshghf";
    function reverseString(strr){
       if (!strr.length){
          var result="";
          for(var i=strr.length;i>0;i++){
              var a=strr.chatAt(i);
              result+=a;
          }
       }return result;
   }
console.log(reverseString(a))
```

When I tried to run it it returned me "undefined". I wonder what's the problem here.

Comment: you have a typo, `charAt` not `chatAt`. You can also simply use `strr[i]` to get the char. Also, you should do `i--` and `i >= 0` if you start at `strr.length`, otherwise for loop is immediately completed at the condition check

Comment: The `if` logic is backwards also. Doesn't make sense to parse the string if it has no length and when it has length then `result` is undefined

Comment: So stupid questionsss! Ignore me plz. THANKS FOR ALL THE HELP

Comment: You said you got error when you were trying to remove duplicates in the string, but your code is about reversing the string!

Comment: a full answer on how reverse a string is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958908/how-do-you-reverse-a-string-in-place-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

> Have a look:

```js
var a = "gsdgtrshghf";

function reverseString(strr) {
  var result = "";

  if (strr.length != null) {
    for (var i = strr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      var a = strr.charAt(i);
      result += a;
    }
  }
  return result;
}
console.log(reverseString(a));

// Better
const reverse = str => Array.from(str).reverse().join('');

console.log(reverse('foo  bar mañana mañana'));
```

> Explanation

1. It's `charAt(i)` not `chatAt(i)`
2. Loop should start from length - 1 and end at 0 and `i` should be decremented
3. And finally declare the variable outside of if

i.e `for(var i = strr.length - ; i >= 0; i--){`
not `for(var i=strr.length;i>0;i++){`

4. Better yet, use combo of `Array.from(str).reverse().join('')`, as it even works with Unicode characters, as pointed out in comments by gaetanoM

Answer (score 0):

The main reason is you are declaring `var result=""` and returning from outside of if(so it become undefined as its scope is only inside if statement) and other errors areas mention in comments `you have a typo, charAt not chatAt. You can also simply use strr[i] to get the char. Also, you should do i-- and i >= 0 if you start at strr.length, otherwise for loop is immediately completed at the condition check`. Check the below code.

```js
var a = "gsdgtrshghf";
    function reverseString(strr){
       var result="";
       if (strr.length){
          
          for(var i=strr.length-1;i>=0;i--){
              var a=strr.charAt(i);
              result+=a;
          }
       }
       return result;
   }
console.log(reverseString(a))
```