# How to write my own method with String.prototype?

Tags: javascript

I want to write my own method which reverses a string. myStr.reverseString should return it reversed. I don't want to use parenthesis at the end of my command like `myStr.reverseString()`

```js
String.prototype.reverseString(){ // This line need to be changed
  return String.split("").reverse().join(""); // This line need to be changed
}

let myStr = "Hello World!"
console.log(myStr.reverseString); // Should expected "!dlroW olleH"
```

Comment: I don't want to use paranthesis at the end.

Comment: `I don't want to use paranthesis at the end of my command like myStr.reverseString()` - May I ask why? It seems to me that only serves to confuse the heck out of people.

Comment: You can define a getter property on the `String.prototype`, but it's generally considered a bad practice to mess with built-in prototypes: `Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, 'reverseString', { get() { return this.split('').reverse().join(''); } })`

Comment: If you don't want to call it with `()`, it's not a method. You're looking for a getter property.

Comment: You could call it using \`\` like so `myStr.reverseString\`\``, that way you won't need the `()`. You would, of course, need to fix the other issues with your code (String to `this` and use of the `function` keyword)

Comment: For other people reading this question please never do this, that lack of parenthesis is a ruby thing that shouldn't exist in JavaScript because it should be clear when a function is being executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can accomplish this by using [defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty).

In order to not use the (), you need to define a getter on String.protoype.

Your code should follow the steps bellow:

1. [Split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)
2. [Reverse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse)
3. [join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

In the end, you will have something like this:

```
    Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, 'reverseString', { get() { return this.split('').reverse().join(''); } })

    let myStr = "Hello World!" 

    console.log(myStr.reverseString); // Should expected "!dlroW olleH"
```

---

[Update]
Although this is the answer to this question, be careful while doing this. Please read: [Why is extending native objects a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034180/why-is-extending-native-objects-a-bad-practice)

[Update 2] As @Ivan Castellanos said, this method won't work for complex strings like: ‍‍‍., if you need to to this, please read: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16776621/800817

Comment: This doesn't work for complex strings such as one containing the family emoji Just try '‍‍‍'.reverseString, instead of getting the same emoji you get "��‍��‍��‍��"

Comment: You are right! It doesn't. Please post an answer that can handle it so we can learn this. Thank you! I can update my answer and mention you.

Comment: It has been answered before, check it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16776621/800817 ,TLDR: UTF-16 Surrogate pairs represent a single character, while .split("") breaks by code-point so inversing such code-points creates an error

Answer (score -1):

Okay Try this, this will help you.

```js
 Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, 'reverse', { get() { 
      // Step 1. Use the split() method to return a new array
    var splitString = this.split(""); // var splitString = "hello".split("");
    // ["h", "e", "l", "l", "o"]
 
    // Step 2. Use the reverse() method to reverse the new created array
    var reverseArray = splitString.reverse(); // var reverseArray = ["h", "e", "l", "l", "o"].reverse();
    // ["o", "l", "l", "e", "h"]
 
    // Step 3. Use the join() method to join all elements of the array into a string
    var joinArray = reverseArray.join(""); // var joinArray = ["o", "l", "l", "e", "h"].join("");
    // "olleh"
    
    //Step 4. Return the reversed string
    return joinArray; } })



var x = 'Friday call peter parker';
    console.log(x.reverse);
```

Comment: "_I don't want to use parenthesis at the end of my command like `myStr.reverseString()`_"

Comment: but why, whats the difference, with or without parentheses??

Comment: [Someone already asked that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56817784/how-to-write-my-own-method-with-string-prototype#comment100188828_56817784), but OP didn't provide an answer. But that doens't mean that you should give an answer to what OP explicitly didn't ask.