# How can I turn the reverseString function into a variable like sum. Is there a difference?

Tags: javascript, code-cleanup, ecmascript-2016

I want to learn how to clean my code up and I feel like the reverse string function can be turned into a variable. Is this possible?

```js
function reverseString(str) {
  return str.split('').reduce((revString, char) => char + revString, '');
}
const reverse = reverseString('Cornell');
console.log(reverse);


const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
const sum = numbers.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue, 0);
console.log(sum);
```

Comment: Make it a variable `const reverseStr = 'Cornell'.split('').reduce((revString, char) => char + revString, '');` ?

Comment: I came back with an error `const reverseStr = str.split('').reduce((revString, char) => char + revString, '');
console.log(reverseStr);` the error is saying str is not defined!

Comment: See my updated comment. But I think what you currently have is better as you can reverse any string without needing to repeat your logic

Comment: I'm assuming cause numbers is previously set it is called in the variable, unlike **reverseString** it has to be in a function with an argument maybe. just what I'm thinking

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks @NickParsons

Comment: If you create a variable `const str = "Cornell";` then you can reference it like you did with `numbers`: `str.split('').reduce...`

Comment: `const reverseStr = (str) => str.split('').reduce((revString, char) => char + revString, '');
console.log(reverseStr('Nick'));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why the reduce?

["As long as you're dealing with simple ASCII characters, and you're happy to use built-in functions, this will work:"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/959004/295783)

```js
console.log(
  'Cornell'.split("").reverse().join("")
)


// as a const:

const rev = str => str.split("").reverse().join("")
console.log(rev('Cornell'))
```

Comment: There's a popular [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16776621/989121) here about `split.reverse` being wrong, however, in my personal opinion that comment is wrong and your solution is (the only) right.

Comment: For the same question: "As long as you're dealing with simple ASCII characters, and you're happy to use built-in functions, this will work"

Answer (score 0):

```
const reverseStr = (str) => str.split('').reduce((revString, char) => char + 
revString, '');
console.log(reverseStr('Name'));
```