# Palindromes in Javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, palindrome

My goal is to take each word and compare it to the reverse. The code moves nicely until the `forEach()` loop. Trying `word === word.reverse()` doesn't work, but hopefully you get the idea. I want to compare the word to the reversed version to find the Palindromes. I realize there are ways to do this only using filter, but the goal is to do it with `forEach()`. Any suggestions to a simple fix to this is appreciated. Thanks!

```
//************************* Finding  Palindromes******************/

let arr = "I love Mom she, she is radar mom?"

function pallindromes(arr){
if(arr.length == 0) return console.log(null)the Pa

arr = arr.toLowerCase()
arr = arr.replace(/[?,]/g,"")
arr = arr.split(" ")
arr = [...new Set(arr)]
let newList = []

arr.forEach(word=>{
    if(word === word.reverse()){
        newList.push(word)
    }
})
return console.log(newList)
}

pallindromes(arr)
```

Comment: Should be an error in the console. A string does not have reverse method.

Comment: And you have some error with the line `return console.log(null)the Pa`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**changed :** `word.split("").reverse().join("")`

```js
let arr = "I love Mom she, she is radar mom?"

function pallindromes(arr) {
  if (arr.length == 0) return console.log(null);

  arr = arr.toLowerCase()
  arr = arr.replace(/[?,]/g, "")
  arr = arr.split(" ")
  arr = [...new Set(arr)]
  let newList = []

  arr.forEach(word => {
    if (word === word.split("").reverse().join("")) {
      newList.push(word)
    }
  })
  return console.log(newList)
}

pallindromes(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

String does not have a reverse method, but array does.

So replace `word.reverse()` with `word.split("").reverse().join("")`.

This will make an array, splitting the word on every letter, reverse it, and join it again.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is actually a way to reverse a string in Javascript, because `.reverse()` is only usable [for arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse). A lot of posts and questions cover that.

If I take this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958908/how-do-you-reverse-a-string-in-place-in-javascript), I can reverse a string with `s.split("").reverse().join("");`, so by applying this to your code we get

```js
let arr = "I love Mom she, she is radar mom?"
  
function pallindromes(arr){
  if(arr.length == 0) return console.log(null)
 
  arr = arr.toLowerCase()
  arr = arr.replace(/[?,]/g,"")
  arr = arr.split(" ")
  arr = [...new Set(arr)]
  let newList = []

  arr.forEach(word=>{
    if(word === word.split('').reverse().join('')){
      newList.push(word)
    }
  })
  return console.log(newList)
}
  
pallindromes(arr)
```

returning `[ 'i', 'mom', 'radar' ]`

I would still advise creating a `reverseString()` function, so that people not used to javascript can still easily read your code without having to guess what `.split().reverse().join()` does.

Cheers.