# How to write the reversed Date using cypress

Tags: cypress, reverse

I am using the Cypress to test one Web UI, and entering the menu requires the password.
Password changes every day and it is the current date written backwards:
Example: Todays date is 24.03. and my password is 3042.

I would appreciate the help

```
  const date = require('dayjs')
  cy.log(date().format('DDMM'));
```

I am getting the current date, but typing it backwards makes the problem.

Comment: You can convert the date to a string and use `String.reverse()` method to reverse the date string

Comment: But without a minimal and complete example, it's very hard to reproduce your issue and provide a helpful answer. Please add one: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see [How do you reverse a string in-place in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958908/how-do-you-reverse-a-string-in-place-in-javascript)

```js
const dayMonth = '24.03'
const reverse = dayMonth.split('').reverse().join('').replace('.', '')
expect(reverse).to.eq('3042')
```

The principle is a string is an array of characters, and arrays can easily be reversed.

The result can be joined back into a string, then you need to deal with the decimal separator.

I'm assuming your `dayjs` example is yielding the "forward" date.

Answer (score 1):

```
const dayjs = require('dayjs')
const todaysDate = dayjs().format('DDMM')
const password = todaysDate.split('').reverse().join('')
cy.visit(url);
.
.
.
cy.get('.ng-untouched').type(password);
```

I found the solution to do it like that.
Thank you Very much :D