# Javascript hash replace error

Tags: javascript, hash, replace

What's the problem with this?

the hash is : #/search=hello/somethingelse/

```
window.location.hash.replace(/search=([^\/]*)/gi, "search=" + value);
```

**EDIT:**

I want to change just a specific part of the `hash` not the whole `hash`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`hash.replace()` does not actually change the hash, only return a value (as it is a String function). Try assigning that result, using:

```
window.location.hash = window.location.hash.replace(/search=([^\/]*)/gi, "search=" + value);
```

On the other hand, `window.location.replace()` *is* actually a function that changes the URL, but that does not work directly with regexes.

Answer (score 1):

Did you forget to assign it?

`replace()` is a String function and returns a new String object, it doesn't modify the original String.

```
window.location.hash = window.location.hash.replace(/search=([^\/]*)/gi, "search=" + value);
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript strings are immutable, I believe. (a quick Google search shows that both [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51185/are-javascript-strings-immutable-do-i-need-a-string-builder-in-js) and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_syntax) back me up)

This effectively means their value can't be changed without an assignment statement.

Hence, `String.replace(...)` doesn't change the String's value, but instead returns a new String.

```
var replaced = window.location.hash.replace(/search=([^\/]*)/gi, "search=" + value);
```

Now, since you are presumably trying to change the `window.location.hash` you're probably fishing for...

```
window.location.hash = window.location.hash.replace(/search=([^\/]*)/gi, "search=" + value);
```

Comment: Your second statement is incorrect, their values cannot ever be changed, that's the definition of immutable.

Comment: Jacob, you know what he meant. :-)

Comment: @Jacob Ralkin - This is true, but I was sacrificing accuracy for clarity; from a practical standpoint, for a beginner, I feel the statement is still accurate, though not correct.

Comment: Accurate, though not correct??? What does that mean?