# Remove the # from the variable

Tags: javascript, string

I have this script:

```
<a href="#extensive" class="forward next-content">Menu item</a>
```

I can not edit the html. Only the js. This is my js:

```
// Click
$('.next-content').click(function() {
    var url = $(this).attr('href');

    console.log(url);
});
```

When i click on the a button. I get the variable. The href in the variable. The variable is #extensive. But, how can i remove the # from the variable?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var url = $(this).attr('href').substring(1);
```

Comment: Nice, this is better than what I thought of (string replacing the # with nothing)

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the '#' character

```
url.replace('#','')
```

or substring

```
url.substring(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just do

```
// Click
$('.next-content').click(function() {
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    url=url.replace("#","");
    console.log(url);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can google it easily...

```
var url = $(this).attr('href').substr(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure really.
[This may help.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029201/javascript-hash-replace-error) I would have said replace would have been your best option:

```
url.replace('#', '');
```