# concatenation in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, concatenation

i want to concatenate two string in javascript i.e.

```
$('#bio').css('font-color', result.titlecolor);
```

but i want to put the character # before the result.titlecolor i.e.

```
 $('#bio').css('font-color','#' result.titlecolor);
```

is this right or wrong? thanks

Comment: Gee, did **nobody** realize it's `color`, not `font-color`?

Comment: Laser-focused on the question, man. ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$('#bio').css('color','#' + result.titlecolor);
```

(Edited to reflect @BoltClock's comment about 'color' versus 'font-color'.)

Answer (score 5):

This:

```
'#' result.titlecolor
```

needs to be:

```
'#'+ result.titlecolor
```

In javascript the `+` operator concatenates to strings together (but remember [strings are immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51185/are-javascript-strings-immutable-do-i-need-a-string-builder-in-js), so you are creating a new string when you use it).  It will also allow you to contatenate a string and a non-string together into a string, such as a number and a string.  So this `"The answer is : " + 42` becomes `"The answer is : 42"`  The tricky part comes in because if you try and concatenate to numbers together such as `14 + 08`, you don't get `"1408"` it adds the two numbers together to become `22`.  Logically this makes sense on a simple example, but it can become troublesome when are concatenating variables together which are loosely typed.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#bio').css('font-color', '#' + result.titlecolor);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   $('#bio').css('font-color','#' + result.titlecolor);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `+` operator serves as both the addition operator and [string concatenation operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/String_Operators) in JavaScript. So:

```
1 + 1                   // is 2

'The answer is: ' + 42  // is 'The answer is: 42'

'1' + '1'               // is '11' (!!!)

'1' + 1
1 + '1'                 // are also '11' (!!!!!)
```

As for your code, the CSS specification defines `color` but not `font-color`, so this is what you want:

```
$('#bio').css('color', '#' + result.titlecolor);
```

As a side note, if you ever run into the `'1' + '1'` or `1 + '1'` problem (*e.g.* you are taking a numeric value from a text box), you have to convert the operands to numbers using the [unary plus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators) operator or the [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) function:

```
+'1' + +'1'            // is 2
```