# JavaScript - object sizes

Tags: javascript, json

Forewarning: a potentially silly question, purely out of curiosity.

If, for example, I perform an AJAX request and get back an array of 1,000 objects like this;

```
{
    MinimumDistance: ...,
    MaximumDistance: ...,
    MinimumTime: ...,
    MaximumTime: ...,
    ReallyLongButDescriptivePropertyName: ...
}
```

Will this consume more memory than if I had shorten the member names (e.g. MinDist)?

If so, is there anything I do to lessen the memory footprint of these objects rather than shortening the member names?

Thanks.

Comment: Request fewer objects (by using pagination).

Comment: You could combine some of the keys... instead of Min/Max you could have `DistanceRange: [min, max], TimeRange: [min, max]` for example.

Comment: Given that you can access the members by their names, the names must therefore be stored in memory and so reducing them would save you a trivial amount of memory. (deflate/gzip would reduce the transmission size)

Comment: rel: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5276915/do-common-javascript-implementations-use-string-interning

Comment: Thanks for that, thg435 - I think that answers my question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using longer properties might end up in a longer ( meaning that it occupies more bytes and so more bandwith and more time to reach the client) response. But usually the response is `gzipped` and so the overhead is minimal compared to the usefulness of having understandable property names.
In any case returning 1.000 object is not a good practice, you should page them and keep your response as small as possible, particularly considering that mobile phones have reduced bandwidth

Comment: Thanks, but I'm more wondering about the overhead once the objects are decompressed and stored in memory.

Comment: @Barg that's trivial i think even if your object occupies 5 megabytes of memory (and that's a lot of text) the memory footprint would be very low. The real problem would be the overhead of iterating over big collections, in my  opinion