# React performance implications of long key value on component

Tags: javascript, performance, reactjs, jsx

How does length of a string applied to some component collection created from some set of data like this:

```
{this.state.list.map(item => {
  const url = item.url;
  return (
    <ListItemComponent url={url} key={url}/>
  );
})}
```

**Are there some restrictions? What are performance implications of having long key values?**

*Background. Sometimes we need to create list of items that are very long (like urls with lots of parameters encoded) and only suitable/unique thing to use as natural key is this very long thing.*

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The length of the string you use for your key should not impact performance at all.

Strings in Javascript are immutable and additionally modern Javascript engines use **string interning**, meaning that when your interpreter is checking whether `'/some/url/ === '/some/other/url'` it does not need to traverse each character in the array in `O(n)` linear time, but can simply check whether the two values are the same.

See this answer for more context: [Do common JavaScript implementations use string interning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5276915/do-common-javascript-implementations-use-string-interning)