# javascript string memory allocation

Tags: javascript, windows, memory-management

How does Javascript allocates memory for strings? I ran this simple code in chrome:

```
var s = 'a';
var i;
for (i = 0; i < 5000000; i++) {
    s += 'b';
}

var s2 = s;
s2[4000000] = 'a';
```

and attached Windbg to chrome, added conditional breakpoint in HeapAlloc, VirtualAlloc, and VirtualAllocEx with condition "requested bytes parameter > 4.5M". 
when the above code ran I didn't see any such big allocation in the debugger.
I expected that at least for `s2` I'll see such allocation.

Answer (score 0):

> when the above code ran I didn't see any such big allocation in the debugger.

Here `s += 'b';` has static string `'b'`. It is very likely that [string intering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5276915/do-common-javascript-implementations-use-string-interning) is at play.

Try making these random strings or perhaps numbers as strings.

> I expected that at least for s2 I'll see such allocation.

Here `s2` is just a reference i.e.not creating more allocation. Try copying the whole array.

Comment: I tried with ArrayBuffer as well, no success - I don't see the memory allocations I expected: `var a = new ArrayBuffer(9000000);
   
   var view = new Int8Array(a);
   for(var i = 0; i<view.length; i++){
    view[i] = i;
   }`