# Should I put event names passed to addEventListener in dedicated constants to save space?

Tags: javascript

In my project I have 104 `addEventListener` calls attaching handlers to the `mousedown` event.

So I decided to use variables for those event names, like:

```
var md = "mousedown";

element.addEventListener(md, function(){});
```

to reduce downloaded bytes.

Is it good practice? Did I get more performant code?

Comment: Better question should be "is there a better way to do it to avoid adding 104 event listeners?" Event Delegation is the answer.

Comment: @epascarello listeners are in different places

Comment: @epascarello and project is big

Comment: I'll take a guess that you have 104 elements that you apply the `.addEventListener` to. If so, probably consider event delegation, so you only define the element once. Otherwise, you save *about* half a megabyte by doing this. You can probably save significantly more if you either minify your code or you use gzip when sending the code. And the latter is probably already done anyway.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it good practice?

No. Do not modify your source code to reduce download bytes - modify it to [avoid duplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), to [properly separate concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns), to [reduce coupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming)) and to make it more readable instead. Introducing an extra global variable ambiguously named `md` does not do that. Rather consider a helper function to wrap the whole `addEventListener` call - surely your 104 event listeners share more code than just the event name?

Reducing the number of bytes to be downloaded is the job of a minifier, transport compression, and caching. The former two will handle repeated occurrences of the string `"mousedown"` just fine.

> Did I get more performant code?

Unlikely. String literals [are usually interned](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5276915/1048572) by the engine anyway, and a variable lookup (even for a constant) takes extra time.