# What is the correct concatenation approach in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, optimization, concatenation

I've searched the internet and people suggest using array's then doing arr.join() but then some argue it's slower in firefox, what the correct method?

```
$.each(data.rows, function (i) {
        var row = data.rows[i];
        var htmlRow = '<div class="colour"><img src="' + row[3] + '" alt="' + row[1] + '" /><span>' + row[1] + '</span> <input type="hidden" value="' + row[4] + '"/></div>';

        htmlRow = htmlRow + '<div class="products">';
        for (var k = 6; k < row.length; k++) {

            htmlRow = htmlRow + $('#product').jqote(row[k], '*');
        }
        htmlRow = htmlRow + '</div>';
        $('.body-holder').append('<div class="holder">' + htmlRow + '</div>');
    });
```

Thanks

Comment: Well that depends, what are you trying to do?

Comment: the correct method... http://jsperf.com it and see!

Comment: Take a look @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51185/are-javascript-strings-immutable-do-i-need-a-string-builder-in-js - has benchmarks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dan is right, using [jQuery Templates](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2010/11/30/an-introduction-to-jquery-templates.aspx) is the way to go.  Here is some sample code to help you understand just how much more powerful it is:

```
<!-- SAMPLE TEMPLATE -->
<script id="myTemplate" type="text/html">
    <li class="activity exceptionManager-observation">
        <hr />
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td valign="top">
                    <img class="icon" src="Includes/Images/symbol_error.png" alt="" border="0" />
                </td>
                <td align="left" valign="top">
                    <div class="date">${Date}</div>
                    <div class="rank">${ProjectNumber}</div>
                    <div class="message">${Message}</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </li>
</script>

<script type="javascript">        
var record = {ProjectNumber: '1234', Message: 'This is my rifle! This is my gun!'};

/// <summary>Append's a record into the UI.</summary>    
function Append(record) {
    try {
        var template = $('#myTemplate').tmpl(record);
        template.prependTo('#someListInMyPage');
    }
    catch (err) {
        alert(err);
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a template engine such as [tmpl](http://api.jquery.com/tmpl/)() from jquery.  It is probably not faster than what you are doing but the performance differences are trivial.  That way of building html(as you are doing) will probably get really ugly fast without a proper templating tool.