# CoffeeScript override base types, change value

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, coffeescript

I have a function that override primary types in CoffeeScript, but this function returnin value and I want to change itself.

```
String::replaceAll = (what, to) ->
    regexPattern = new RegExp(what, "g")
    this.replace regexPattern, to
```

Now I have to use this in this way:

```
test = test.replaceAll "sth", "sth2"
```

I want to use this in this way:

```
test.replaceAll "sth", "sth2" # only, without assigning
```

(this = this.replace regexPattern, to # doesn't work)

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Why don;t you accept that this is how it works?

Comment: Less code and don't care about assignment. I have many functions ovverides primary types, I want to use in this way: "some string".func().func1().func2()

Comment: But the default function can be chained, I don't understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings in javascript/coffeescript are immutable and can't be changed once created.  So its not possible to have it modify itself, only to return a new value.  However you can chain your function as it is currently set up if you like, since it does return a value.

so

```
test = test.replaceAll(x,y).replaceAll(a,b)
```

should work fine

#### References

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FData_structures):

> Unlike in languages like C, JavaScript strings are immutable. This means that once a string is created, it is not possible to modify it. However, it is still possible to create another string based on an operation on the original string.

SO:

[Are JavaScript strings immutable? Do I need a "string builder" in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51185/are-javascript-strings-immutable-do-i-need-a-string-builder-in-javascript)