# Scope within HTML5 member function

Tags: javascript, html, function, variables, scope

I am an ancient C programmer attempting to use HTML5, with some difficulty.  I have defined a global function "MouseHandler" with variables local to that function including X and LastMsg.

A function MoveHandler is within MouseHandler, and placing a breakpoint at `if (PostFunc)` I find the value of the local variables to be:

1. ABCStr is "QQQ"
2. DefStr is "Down 417,358"
3. LastMsg is "Down 417,358"
4. Mouse.LastMsg is "QQQ"
5. X is 417
6. LocalX is 417

The code is:

```
var MouseHandler = function (canvas1,   terraincvs1,    PostFunc1)
{
    //  ...
    var X,  Y;
    var LastMsg =   "QQQ";

    //  ...

    function    MoveHandler ()
    {
        var ABCStr      =   Mouse.LastMsg;
        var DEFStr      =   LastMsg;
        var LocalX      =   X;

        //  ...

        LastMsg =   "Move " + X + ',' + Y;

        if  (PostFunc)
            PostFunc    ();
        return      {   "LastMsg"   :   LastMsg     }
    }

    cvs.addEventListener("mousedown", DownListener, false);

    return  { "DownListener" : DownListener, "UpListener" : UpListener, "MoveHandler"  : MoveHandler,
            "OffsetX" : OffsetX, "OffsetY" : OffsetY, "dX" : dX, "dY" : dY, "DownX" : DownX, "DownY" : DownY, "Down" : Down,
            "LastMsg" : LastMsg }
}


//  ...

var Mouse   =   new MouseHandler    (canvas, HexCanvas, PostMouse);
```

It seems that LocalX is appropriately set to the value of "X" defined within the outer function MouseHandler, but LastMsg seems to be an (implicitly declared) local variable within the inner MoveHandler, rather than referring (as I expected) to the LastMsg defined within the outer function MouseHandler.  Using the reference Mouse.LastMsg appears to refer to the value of the outer function's LastMsg, as might be expected.

Am I missing something obvious here?  Can somebody direct me to an online reference for scope of variables for HTML5 that would clarify this issue for me?

Comment: Javascript doesn't have implicit declaration except at the global scope outside  strict mode (with strict mode on, it's an error instead)

Comment: Perhaps you have a timing error of some kind?

Comment: Some overlap with: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work

Comment: Jan - thank you.  Did not directly answer my question but I learned more about strict mode and scope rules that put me on the right path.  Mark - yours also helpful in the same way.

Answer (score 2):

These scoping issues are entirely related to JavaScript, and not so much HTML5.

JavaScript's variable scopes, although appearing to be identical to C-family block scopes, are actually function-level scopes. JavaScript will start with the innermost function and search outwards to "resolve" variables, so because you didn't have a definition of `LastMsg` in your `MoveHandler()` function, JavaScript went up the scope chain to the anonymous function that you defined inside of your `MouseHandler` variable and there it found and resolved `LastMsg` to the string `QQQ`.

When you change the value of `LastMsg` in the `MoveHandler()` function, JavaScript simply discards the `QQQ` values and creates a new string and assigns its reference to that variable because JavaScript strings are *immutable*.

Good links to read about this are:

[JavaScript Scoping and Hoisting](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html)

[What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope#500438)

[Are JavaScript strings immutable? Do I need a "string builder" in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51185/are-javascript-strings-immutable-do-i-need-a-string-builder-in-javascript)