# Caching a big HTTP response?

Tags: javascript, html, system-design

Once authenticated I save a token which is then used to make further requests but then after page refresh the same request for that token has to be sent.

The JSON response is 9MB. I attemped saving it in `localStorage` but it exceeds the quota. Is there any way to do this on the client?

Thanks.

Comment: Use sessionStorage instead.

Comment: @GoldenretriverYT It says that the limit is 5MB.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [localStorage store large size data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17255786/localstorage-store-large-size-data)

Comment: Not of session storage, no. But you can try using the Cache API: https://web.dev/cache-api-quick-guide/

Comment: As mentioned in the above question as well go for either blob, webSQL or indexDB

Comment: What, exactly, is in the JSON response that makes it 9MB?

Comment: @BlackMamba May I ask why you are suggesting WebSQL given that it was deprecated by the W3C almost 10 years ago...

Comment: @Dai I just mentioned the solutions mentioned in the above duplicate question there are many so I won't thrust upon any particular thing

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to handle it:

1. The quota of the local storage can be modified by the user, you can prompt the user to increase the storage.
2. You can compress the data and reduce its size.
3. In chrome if you package it to a chrome app then it allows you to change it.
4. You can use third party library to store such as `Dexie.js`.

Comment: `Dexie.js` is just a (nice) wrapper over IndexedDB, which doesn't offer synchronous access to data, which might break the OP's requirements. Personally I'd just use IndexedDB directly (maybe with a very thin `Promise`-wrapper of my own) because having fewer dependencies is better.