# How can one export filtered data to csv or excel format?

Tags: dc.js

How can one export filtered data to csv or excel format?

This will give me all the current filtered data:
dim.top(Infinity)

Need help pushing the data back to the server and then pushing it to csv/excel or doing everything client side.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really a dc.js question.  There isn't anything built into dc.js or d3.js to write data into csv or json format, probably because writing formats is easier than parsing.

Take a look at, for example:
[How to export JavaScript array info to csv (on client side)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14964035/how-to-export-javascript-array-info-to-csv-on-client-side)

and its correction (it apparently has a bug) here:
[JavaScript array to CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18848860/javascript-array-to-csv)

I don't know if there are libraries to do this.  It's not very complicated to write by hand.

EDIT: I wasn't aware that d3 does have CSV output as well:
https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV#format

Comment: Thanks Gordon, since these solutions behave very inconsistently with different browsers, I may try going the server-side route.

Comment: Yeah, creating the csv text is rock solid, but doing a file download from the client is still shaky. I guess you may have to round trip it to the server just for the download. (I have the same problem.)

Comment: Actually, it's not so hard. [Here's a better answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37573744/676195), with a pointer to an example I added to dc.js.