# Get selected data contained within box select tool in Bokeh

Tags: python, bokeh

If I have a scatter plot in bokeh and I've enabled the Box Select Tool, suppose I select a few points with the Box Select Tool. How can I access the (x,y) position location information of the points that I've selected?

```
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
from random import choice
from string import ascii_lowercase

from bokeh.models.tools import *
from bokeh.plotting import *

output_notebook()


TOOLS="pan,wheel_zoom,reset,hover,poly_select,box_select"
p = figure(title = "My chart", tools=TOOLS)
p.xaxis.axis_label = 'X'
p.yaxis.axis_label = 'Y'

source = ColumnDataSource(
    data=dict(
        xvals=list(range(0, 10)),
        yvals=list(np.random.normal(0, 1, 10)),
        letters = [choice(ascii_lowercase) for _ in range(10)]
    )
)
p.scatter("xvals", "yvals",source=source,fill_alpha=0.2, size=5)

select_tool = p.select(dict(type=BoxSelectTool))[0]

show(p)

# How can I know which points are contained in the Box Select Tool?
```

I can't call the "callback" attribute and the "dimensions" attribute just returns a list ["width", "height"]. If I can just get the dimensions and the location of the Selected Box, I can figure out which points are in my dataset from there.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use a `callback` on the `ColumnDataSource` that updates a Python variable with the indices of the selected data:

```
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
from random import choice
from string import ascii_lowercase

from bokeh.models.tools import *
from bokeh.plotting import *
from bokeh.models import CustomJS



output_notebook()


TOOLS="pan,wheel_zoom,reset,hover,poly_select,box_select"
p = figure(title = "My chart", tools=TOOLS)
p.xaxis.axis_label = 'X'
p.yaxis.axis_label = 'Y'

source = ColumnDataSource(
    data=dict(
        xvals=list(range(0, 10)),
        yvals=list(np.random.normal(0, 1, 10)),
        letters = [choice(ascii_lowercase) for _ in range(10)]
    )
)
p.scatter("xvals", "yvals",source=source,fill_alpha=0.2, size=5)

select_tool = p.select(dict(type=BoxSelectTool))[0]

source.callback = CustomJS(args=dict(p=p), code="""
        var inds = cb_obj.get('selected')['1d'].indices;
        var d1 = cb_obj.get('data');
        console.log(d1)
        var kernel = IPython.notebook.kernel;
        IPython.notebook.kernel.execute("inds = " + inds);
        """
)

show(p)
```

Then you can access the desired data attributes using something like

```
zip([source.data['xvals'][i] for i in inds],
    [source.data['yvals'][i] for i in inds])
```

Comment: Awesome! I just had to change CustomJS to "Callback" (still have version 0.9.0). Thanks for your help, really useful.

Comment: @FrankFineis: Glad it helps! Feel free to upvote (by clicking the triangle) and accept the answer (by clicking the tick mark) to remove the question from the "unanswered" list (and to give me some internet points `=)`)

Answer (score 6):

#### Here is a working example with Python 3.7.5 and Bokeh 1.4.0

*public github link to this jupyter notebook:*
https://github.com/surfaceowl-ai/python_visualizations/blob/master/notebooks/bokeh_save_linked_plot_data.ipynb

#### environment report:

*virtual env python version:* Python 3.7.5 
*virtual env ipython version:* 7.9.0

#### watermark package reports:

bokeh 1.4.0 
jupyter 1.0.0 
numpy 1.17.4 
pandas 0.25.3 
rise 5.6.0 
watermark 2.0.2

```
# Generate linked plots + TABLE displaying data + save button to export cvs of selected data

from random import random

from bokeh.io import output_notebook  # prevent opening separate tab with graph
from bokeh.io import show

from bokeh.layouts import row
from bokeh.layouts import grid
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models import Button  # for saving data
from bokeh.models.widgets import DataTable, DateFormatter, TableColumn
from bokeh.models import HoverTool
from bokeh.plotting import figure


# create data
x = [random() for x in range(500)]
y = [random() for y in range(500)]

# create first subplot
plot_width = 400
plot_height = 400

s1 = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x, y=y))
fig01 = figure(
    plot_width=plot_width,
    plot_height=plot_height,
    tools=["lasso_select", "reset", "save"],
    title="Select Here",
)
fig01.circle("x", "y", source=s1, alpha=0.6)

# create second subplot
s2 = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=[], y=[]))

# demo smart error msg:  `box_zoom`, vs `BoxZoomTool`
fig02 = figure(
    plot_width=400,
    plot_height=400,
    x_range=(0, 1),
    y_range=(0, 1),
    tools=["box_zoom", "wheel_zoom", "reset", "save"],
    title="Watch Here",
)

fig02.circle("x", "y", source=s2, alpha=0.6, color="firebrick")

# create dynamic table of selected points
columns = [
    TableColumn(field="x", title="X axis"),
    TableColumn(field="y", title="Y axis"),
]

table = DataTable(
    source=s2,
    columns=columns,
    width=400,
    height=600,
    sortable=True,
    selectable=True,
    editable=True,
)

# fancy javascript to link subplots
# js pushes selected points into ColumnDataSource of 2nd plot
# inspiration for this from a few sources:
# credit: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1097752/iolsmit via: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48982260/bokeh-lasso-select-to-table-update
# credit: https://stackoverflow.com/users/8412027/joris via: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34164587/get-selected-data-contained-within-box-select-tool-in-bokeh

s1.selected.js_on_change(
    "indices",
    CustomJS(
        args=dict(s1=s1, s2=s2, table=table),
        code="""
        var inds = cb_obj.indices;
        var d1 = s1.data;
        var d2 = s2.data;
        d2['x'] = []
        d2['y'] = []
        for (var i = 0; i < inds.length; i++) {
            d2['x'].push(d1['x'][inds[i]])
            d2['y'].push(d1['y'][inds[i]])
        }
        s2.change.emit();
        table.change.emit();

        var inds = source_data.selected.indices;
        var data = source_data.data;
        var out = "x, y\\n";
        for (i = 0; i < inds.length; i++) {
            out += data['x'][inds[i]] + "," + data['y'][inds[i]] + "\\n";
        }
        var file = new Blob([out], {type: 'text/plain'});

    """,
    ),
)

# create save button - saves selected datapoints to text file onbutton
# inspriation for this code:
# credit:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31824124/is-there-a-way-to-save-bokeh-data-table-content
# note: savebutton line `var out = "x, y\\n";` defines the header of the exported file, helpful to have a header for downstream processing

savebutton = Button(label="Save", button_type="success")
savebutton.callback = CustomJS(
    args=dict(source_data=s1),
    code="""
        var inds = source_data.selected.indices;
        var data = source_data.data;
        var out = "x, y\\n";
        for (i = 0; i < inds.length; i++) {
            out += data['x'][inds[i]] + "," + data['y'][inds[i]] + "\\n";
        }
        var file = new Blob([out], {type: 'text/plain'});
        var elem = window.document.createElement('a');
        elem.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
        elem.download = 'selected-data.txt';
        document.body.appendChild(elem);
        elem.click();
        document.body.removeChild(elem);
        """,
)

# add Hover tool
# define what is displayed in the tooltip
tooltips = [
    ("X:", "@x"),
    ("Y:", "@y"),
    ("static text", "static text"),
]

fig02.add_tools(HoverTool(tooltips=tooltips))

# display results
# demo linked plots
# demo zooms and reset
# demo hover tool
# demo table
# demo save selected results to file

layout = grid([fig01, fig02, table, savebutton], ncols=3)

output_notebook()
show(layout)

# things to try:
# select random shape of blue dots with lasso tool in 'Select Here' graph
# only selected points appear as red dots in 'Watch Here' graph -- try zooming, saving that graph separately
# selected points also appear in the table, which is sortable
# click the 'Save' button to export a csv

# TODO:  export from Bokeh to pandas dataframe
```