# Plotting a selection of data from Bokeh using Lasso

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, bokeh

I have some data that I've been plotting with Bokeh.  It's the result of some manifold learning analysis scrunched down to 2 dimensions.  What I want to do is select a portion of the datapoints using the lasso tool, and then plot a histogram of say one particular feature of those data points.

Using this post:
[Get selected data contained within box select tool in Bokeh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34164587/get-selected-data-contained-within-box-select-tool-in-bokeh)

and this

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/linking.html

I learned you can get the indices after selecting and also have plots where data is linked to one another.  I am able to use these indices to then select the subset of datapoints with one feature i'm interested in.  However, I'd like to be able to streamline this.  When i do the lasso select, I want another plot to generate the histogram of the selected indices.  My problem is in dealing with the callbacks.  I can't seem to get the order right, and I can't seem to figure out how to link the plots to one another.

```
x = range(0, len(x_toPlot[:,0]))
y0 = x_toPlot[:,0]
y1 = x_toPlot[:,1]

# create a column data source for the plots to share
source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x, y0=y0, y1=y1))
testSource= ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x, y0=y0))

TOOLS = "lasso_select,help"

# create a new plot and add a renderer
left = figure(tools=TOOLS, width=300, height=300, title=None)
left.circle('y0', 'y1', source=source)

# create another new plot and add a renderer
middle = figure(tools=TOOLS, width=300, height=300, title=None)
middle.circle('x', 'y1', source=source)


right = figure(tools=TOOLS, width=300, height=300, title=None)
right.circle('x','y0', source=testSource)

p = gridplot([[left, middle]])


#create a function aboeve.. and then call that funciton in here...
source.callback = CustomJS(args=dict(p=p), code="""
        var inds = cb_obj.get('selected')['1d'].indices;
        var d1 = cb_obj.get('data');
        console.log(d1)
        var kernel = IPython.notebook.kernel;
        IPython.notebook.kernel.execute("inds = " + inds);
        IPython.notebook.kernel.execute("updateInds(inds)");


        IPython.notebook.kernel.execute("res=X['education_num']");
        IPython.notebook.kernel.execute("res=res.loc[inds2]");        
        IPython.notebook.kernel.execute("testSource= ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=inds2, y0=res))");
        IPython.notebook.kernel.execute("right = figure(tools=TOOLS, width=300, height=300, title=None)");
        IPython.notebook.kernel.execute("right.circle('x','y0', source=testSource)");
        IPython.notebook.kernel.execute("p2 = gridplot([[ right]])");        
        IPython.notebook.kernel.execute("push_notebook(p2)");


        """
)
```

and there is some other function i was trying to call called updateInds which would update the indices as i select using lasso

```
def updateInds(f):
    global inds2
    inds2=list(f)
    print ("hello")
    global testingThing
    testingThing=zip([source.data['x'][i] for i in inds],    [source.data['y0'][i] for i in inds])
    push_notebook()
```

I'm working within a Jupyter notebook environment.

Comment: I'd suggest trying to adapt this example: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/app/selection_histogram.py