# bokeh: How to edit a df or CDS-object through box_select?

Tags: python, bokeh, pandas-bokeh

I'm trying to label a pandas-df (containing timeseries data) with the help of 
a bokeh-lineplot, box_select tool and a TextInput widget in a jupyter-notebook. How can I access the by the box_select selected data points?

I tried to edit a similar problems code ([Get selected data contained within box select tool in Bokeh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34164587/get-selected-data-contained-within-box-select-tool-in-bokeh?rq=1)) by changing the CustomJS to something like:

```
source.callback = CustomJS(args=dict(p=p), code="""
        var inds = cb_obj.get('selected')['1d'].indices;
        [source.data['xvals'][i] for i in inds] = 'b'
        """
)
```

but couldn't apply a change on the source of the selected points.

So the shortterm goal is to manipulate a specific column of source of the selected points.

Longterm I want to use a TextInput widget to label the selected points by the supplied Textinput. That would look like:

[image]

**EDIT:**

That's the current code I'm trying in the notebook, to reconstruct the issue:

```
from random import random

import bokeh as bk
from bokeh.layouts import row
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, ColumnDataSource, HoverTool
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show, output_notebook

output_notebook()

x = [random() for x in range(20)]
y = [random() for y in range(20)]

hovertool=HoverTool(tooltips=[("Index", "$index"), ("Label", "@label")])

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x, y=y, label=[i for i in "a"*20]))
p1 = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400, tools="box_select", title="Select Here")
p1.circle('x', 'y', source=source, alpha=0.6)
p1.add_tools(hovertool)
source.selected.js_on_change('indices', CustomJS(args=dict(source=source), code="""
        var inds = cb_obj.indices;
        for (var i = 0; i < inds.length; i++) {
            source.data['label'][inds[i]] = 'b'
        }
        source.change.emit();
    """)
)

layout = row(p1)

show(layout)
```

Answer (score 1):

The main thing to note is that BokehJS can only *automatically* notice updates when actual assignments are made, e.g.

```
source.data = some_new_data
```

That would trigger an update. If you update the data "in place" then BokehJS is not able to notice that. You will have to be explicit and call `source.change.emit()` to let BokehJS know something has been updated.

However, you should also know that you are using three different things that are long-deprecated and will be removed in the release after next.

- `cb_obj.get('selected')`

  There is no need to ever use `.get` You can just access properties directly:

  ```
  cb_obj.selected
  ```
- The `['1d']` syntax. This dict approach was very clumsy and will be removed very soon. For most selections you want the `indices` property of the selection:

  ```
  source.selected.indices
  ```
- `source.callback`

  This is an ancient ad-hoc callback. There is a newer general mechanism for callbacks on properties that should always be used instead

  ```
  source.selected.js_on_change('indices', CustomJS(...))
  ```

  Note that in this case, the `cb_obj` is the selection, not the data source.

Comment: Thanks @bigreddot! I changed the code to:
```source.selected.js_on_change('indices',CustomJS(args=dict(source=source), code="""
        var inds = cb_obj.indices;
        for (var i = 0; i < inds.length; i++) {
            source.data['label'][inds[i]] = 'b'
        }        
        source.change.emit()
        """)```
and used a Hovertool to check the 'label' entry. In fact it changes in the plot. Nevertheless after checking source.data in the next cell it has no 'b' in source.data['label'] despite using source.change.emit().

Comment: Is it even possible to change the source object within a jupyter-environment or do I have to set it up as a bokeh serve?

Comment: If you just want to change the JavaScript side, from Python, you can use `push_notebook`. If you want the Python side to update in response to changes in the JavaScript side, that requires a Bokeh server app. The Bokeh server *is the thing* that performs the work to keep both sides synchronized.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of this guide on [how to embed a bokeh server in the notebook](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/1.3.4/examples/howto/server_embed/notebook_embed.ipynb) I figured out the following minimal example for my purpose:

```
from random import random
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from bokeh.io import output_notebook, show
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models import Button
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import HoverTool, ColumnDataSource, BoxSelectTool
from bokeh.models.widgets import TextInput
output_notebook()

def modify_doc(doc):
    # create a plot and style its properties
    TOOLS="pan,wheel_zoom,reset"
    p = figure(title = "My chart", tools=TOOLS)
    p.xaxis.axis_label = 'X'
    p.yaxis.axis_label = 'Y'
    hovertool=HoverTool(tooltips=[("Index", "$index"), ("Label", "@label")])

    source = ColumnDataSource(
    data=dict(
            xvals=list(range(0, 10)),
            yvals=list(np.random.normal(0, 1, 10)),
            label = [i for i in "a"*10]
    ))
    p.scatter("xvals", "yvals",source=source, color="white")
    p.line("xvals", "yvals",source=source)
    p.add_tools(BoxSelectTool(dimensions="width"))
    p.add_tools(hovertool)

    # create a callback that will add a number in a random location
    def callback():
            inds = source.selected.indices
            for i in inds:
                    source.data['label'][i] = label_input.value.strip()
            print(source.data)
            new_data =  pd.DataFrame(source.data)
            new_data.to_csv("new_data.csv", index=False)

    # TextInput to specify the label
    label_input = TextInput(title="Label")
    # add a button widget and configure with the call back
    button = Button(label="Label Data")
    button.on_click(callback)

    # put the button and plot in a layout and add to the document
    doc.add_root(column(button,label_input, p))

show(modify_doc, notebook_url="http://localhost:8888")
```

That generates the following UI:
[image]

BTW: Due to the non-existing box_select tool for the line glyph I use a workaround by combining it with invisible scatter points.

So far so good, is there a more elegant way to access the data.source/new_data df in the notebook outside modify_doc() than exporting it within the callback?