# How to create a excel sheet from 2D Array In Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to create excel sheet from the 2-dimensional array.

I apologie for demanding code from scratch.

```
    function downloadableCSV(rows) {
      var content = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,";

      rows.forEach(function(row, index) {
        content += row.join(",") + "\n";
      });

      return encodeURI(content);
    }

    var rows = [
      ["name1", 2, 3],
      ["name2", 4, 5],
      ["name3", 6, 7],
      ["name4", 8, 9],
      ["name5", 10, 11]
    ];

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#download").click(function() {
          downloadableCSV(rows);
        });

    });
```

I got this code from [others fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cuguafw1/). For any reason, the code seems not working.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use ExcelPlus api. Just add two lines to call the necessary files:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/CHOOSE_A_VERSION/xlsx.core.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="excelplus-2.5.min.js"></script>
```

An example about how to write/create an Excel file:

```
// --- EXAMPLE 1 ---
// in this example we want to build an Excel file with one sheet and write some stuff
var ep=new ExcelPlus();
// We're going to do several tasks in one line of code:
// 1) create an Excel with one sheet called "Book1"
// 2) write some data from an array to the new-created sheet
// 3) create a new sheet called "Book2"
// 4) write "A1" in cell "A1" of the new-created sheet
// 5) write the today date in D1 of the "Book1" sheet
// 6) save it on the user computer (this last step only works with IE10+ and modern browsers)
ep.createFile("Book1")
  .write({ "content":[ ["A1","B1","C1"] ] })
  .createSheet("Book2")
  .write({ "cell":"A1", "content":"A1" })
  .write({ "sheet":"Book1", "cell":"D1", "content":new Date() })
  .saveAs("demo.xlsx");
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. i have updated my question, can you correct me there plz.

Answer (score -2):

You cannot create Excel files manually. But you can create .csv files which can be read by Excel. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18848860/javascript-array-to-csv) post.