# Print 2 arrays into a CSV file with javascript

Tags: javascript, csv, export

I was following the mentioned question and this one:
[JavaScript array to CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18848860/javascript-array-to-csv)

Trying to print 2 arrays in columns A and B which i can turn into a string separated by comas"," which ever is more easy to do but i just can´t get it to work with the examples available.

My arrays look like this:

```
var Test = ["John", "Ivar", "Peter", "Tony"];
var Addres = ["Canada", "Sweden", "England", "Chile"];
```

And in string format its the same only separated by comas

I thought it was going to be an easy task but it's more complicated than I expected

Hope anyone here can help me with this,

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish it with one-liner `reduce`:

```
var Test = ["John", "Ivar", "Peter", "Tony"];
var Addres = ["Canada", "Sweden", "England", "Chile"];

var result = Test.reduce((str, name, i) => `${str}${name},${Address[i]}\n`, 'Test,Address\n');

console.log(result);
```