# Cannot overwrite "this" in javascript when extending String with String.prototype

Tags: javascript, string, prototype, immutability

I want to create a mutable `reverse` method for a javascript string.

**TL; DR:**

Here is my attempt that did not work:

```
String.prototype.reverse = function() {


    var reversed = {};
    j = 0;
    for (i = this.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        reversed[j++] = this[i];
    }
    for (i in reversed)
    {
        this[i] = reversed[i];
    }
};
```

...

```
str1 = "hello";
str1.reverse();
console.log(str1); //hello, not olleh
```

It doesn't change the string at all, as further evidenced by this small test:

```
String.prototype.makeFirstCharX = function() {
    console.log(this[0]); //h
    this[0] = 'x'; //no error
    console.log(this[0]); //h ??
};

str1.makeFirstCharX();
console.log(str1); //hello, not xello
```

**Is there anyway to overwrite values of `this` in a new protoype function for a native JS type? Why doesn't something like `this[0]='x'` give an error instead of just silently failing?**

---This is what I tried on a custom JS object that *did* work as expected, which is what I based the above off of:

I can create a custom revsersible string that behaves similarly to a native string like this:

```
    function MyString(str) {
//set string content and length
        var l = 0;
        for (i in str)
        {
            this[i] = str[i];
            l++;
        }
        this.length = l;

    }
    MyString.prototype.toString = function()
    {
        var retVal = '';
        for (i = 0; i < this.length; i++)
        {
            retVal += this[i];
        }
        return retVal;
    };

    MyString.prototype.reverse = function()
    {
        var reversed = {};
        j = 0;
        for (i = this.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            reversed[j++] = this[i];
        }
        for (i in reversed)
        {
            this[i] = reversed[i];
        }
    };
```

So as expected:

```
    str = new MyString('string');
    console.log(str); // MyString { 0="s", 1="t", 2="r", more...}
    console.log("" + str); //string
    console.log(str.length); //6
    str.reverse();
    console.log(str); // MyString { 0="g", 1="n", 2="i", more...}
    console.log("" + str); //gnirts
```

**But if I try the same thing on a "real" javascript string, it does not work.**

Comment: Short answer: Strings in javascript are immutables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bracket notation isn't going to work. From [String](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String):

> For character access using bracket notation, attempting to delete or
>   assign a value to these properties will not succeed. The properties
>   involved are neither writable nor configurable. (See
>   Object.defineProperty for more information.)

Strings are immutable in Javascript so you're not going to be able to change them by any means.

Comment: Thanks, this at least explains why overwriting this will silently fail.

Answer (score 4):

[First Strings aren't mutable in Javascript.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51185/are-javascript-strings-immutable-do-i-need-a-string-builder-in-javascript)

from the [rhino book](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596000486/):

> In JavaScript, strings are immutable objects, which means that the
>   characters within them may not be changed and that any operations on
>   strings actually create new strings. Strings are assigned by
>   reference, not by value. In general, when an object is assigned by
>   reference, a change made to the object through one reference will be
>   visible through all other references to the object. Because strings
>   cannot be changed, however, you can have multiple references to a
>   string object and not worry that the string value will change without
>   your knowing it

Also Javascript [passes it by value](http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/javascript_pass). Which means that you aren't modifying your original string anywhere. You have to return something.

Here's a simple implementation for the reverse function:

```
function reverse(s) {
  var reversed = '';
  for (var i = s.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    reversed += s[i];
  return reversed;
}
```

You have to reassign the original var.

```
var original = 'original';
original = reverse(original);
```