# Javascript for loop running out of sequence

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

I have a confusing problem where a line of code in my function is running before a loop which is stated above it.  In my HTML I have:

```
<textarea id="textBox"></textarea>
<button id="submitButton" onclick="parseData()">submit</button>
<div id="put"></div>
```

And my JS function is:

```
function parseData() {
    var data = $("#textBox").val();
    var tab = /\t/;
    data = data.split(tab);
    $("#put").html($("#put").html() + "<table>");
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        $("#put").html($("#put").html() + "<tr>"+data[i]+"</tr>");
    };
    $("#put").html($("#put").html() + "</table>");
    return;
};
```

The resulting html in `$("#put")` is this:

```
<table></table>
"SiO2 (%)Al2O3 (%)TiO2 (%)CaO2 (%)MgO2 (%) 8.21.25.31.51.8 45.32.52.60.210.5 65.23.48.70.0662.3 20.11.85.42.540.2 18.91.12.34.810.7"
```

I'm not sure why the final `</table>` is being placed before the `for` loop runs, and I'm not sure why the `<tr>` tags aren't being added within the for loop.  Any pointers?

Comment: You can't add partial HTML to `html()`, it expects valid HTML, with opening and closing tags etc. so it can build the elements. Use a variable to store the HTML string instead, and use `html()` only once, when the loop has completed.

Comment: You should also concatenate the entire HTML string before appending it - it'll make the code above much cleaner and improve performance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery automatically closes up tags upon insertion. Try this.

```
function parseData() {
    var data = $("#textBox").val();
    var tab = /\t/;
    var put_html = $("#put").html() + "<table>";
    data = data.split(tab);
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        put_html += "<tr>"+data[i]+"</tr>";
    };
    put_html += '</table>';
    $("#put").html(put_html);
    return;
};
```

However, I notice that you aren't using `<td>` elements. You might want to look into fixing that too.

Comment: Perfect - didn't know jQuery auto-closed tags.  Thanks so much!  The `<td>` thing was an accidental deletion when I was testing solutions - thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 2):

Every time you are adding content into the `html()` property rather than building the entire content and adding it.

Since you are using jQuery you can bind the event using jQuery rather than adding that directly in the HTML

```
<textarea id="textBox"></textarea>
<button id="submitButton">submit</button>
<div id="put"></div>

$(function(){
    $("#submitButton").click(function(){
        parseData();
    });

    function parseData() {
        var data = $("#textBox").val();
        var tab = /\t/;
        data = data.split(tab);

        // Build your html
        $("#put").html('htmlstructure');
        return;
    }
});
```

Also you can look for something similar like concatenating the string in an array so that you don't create string isntances each time when you append, since strings are immutable.

[Good example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51185/are-javascript-strings-immutable-do-i-need-a-string-builder-in-javascript)