# How does Falcor Model handle references to strings?

Tags: javascript, reference, data-consistency, falcor

In Javascript, [strings are immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4717855/115493), and making references to strings is equivalent to copying the string istelf.

In Falcor, I can make references to strings using `{$type:"ref", value:[...]}`. Falcor claims to maintain data consistency, so that if the model contains references, they end up pointing to the same JS object (so maintaining consistency becomes trivial).

> <sup>From [Falcor docs on JSON Graph](https://netflix.github.io/falcor/documentation/jsongraph.html):</sup>
>   JSON Graph allows a graph to be modeled as JSON without introducing duplicates. Instead of inserting an entity into the same message multiple times, each entity with a unique identifier is inserted into a **single**, globally unique location in the JSON Graph object.

However, I can't see how this could apply to strings.

Let say, I have a model like this:

```
{jsonGraph:{
    foo: {text: 'aaa'},
    bar: {text: {$type: "ref", value: ["foo", "text"]}},
}}
```

What happens when I update `foo.text`? Will `bar.text` be updated too? And if yes, how does it work?

Answer (score 1):

> What happens when I update `foo.text`? Will `bar.text` be updated too?

If you update `foo.text` and then `get('bar.text')` you'll get whatever the current value of `foo.text` is. It's *as if* the value got updated in both places, if you want to think of it that way.

But really there is no `bar.text` value, it's just a reference, and if the thing being referenced changes, then things that follow that reference will encounter that new value.

Think of it like this:

```
var text = '123';
function getText() {
  return text;
}
```

`getText()` behaves like a reference to `text`. If you set `text = 456` then `getText()` will start returning a different value, even if `getText()` didn't itself change.