# is object mutable in javascript? If yes, why the object of string is immutable then?

Tags: javascript, node.js

In **javascript** only **object** and **arrays** are **mutable** and remaining are **primitive** type which are **immutable**. However if we create an object of string,then it can't be mutated.
why is that?

```
var a = new String("abc")
a.toUpperCase();
console.log(a) /*wont print "ABC" and prints an object with String:abc. Concludes 
that string object is immutable.*/
```

Comment: "*Concludes that string object is immutable.*" No, it concludes that *this method* does not mutate the instance. If you were to do `a.foo = "hello"` and then `console.log(a.foo)` you'd see that the instance *has* been mutated.

Comment: [More examples of your title](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+string+object+mutable+site%3Astackoverflow.com)

Comment: @VLAZ its a.foo which returns a mutated value. i was talking about a.

Comment: What is your source for the split in mutability between object/array and "primitive" types?

Comment: Many dupes like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35443406/how-to-set-update-the-value-of-a-string-object-in-javascript) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51185/are-javascript-strings-immutable-do-i-need-a-string-builder-in-javascript)

Comment: @abhishek61067 `a` ***is*** the string object. It is mutable as I showed above, since you can change it. Mutation = change. A *method* is not obliged to mutate the associated object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, yes, objects are mutable.

The reason that "string objects" - created with `new String` - are not mutable is that string objects result in objects [which have an internal `StringData` property](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-stringcreate):

> Set S.[[StringData]] to value.

That `StringData` is what is retrieved when the string object is coerced back to a primitive.

If the interpreter provided a way to change this `StringData` internal slot - then these sorts of objects would effectively be mutable. (Similarly, `Set.add` changes a Set's internal slot, and the same sort of mechanism exists for many other objects in JS - an exposed method changes values held in internal slots.)

But

```
a.toUpperCase();
```

alone wouldn't do anything - `toUpperCase` returns a new string. There are no methods (in standard implementations) that exist that can alter a string object's `StringData` internal slot - all you can do is create a new string object with a different `StringData`.

You could also strongly consider just not using string objects at all.

Comment: So that mean, using string literal and string object are pretty similar? Both are immutables!

Comment: Kind of. The string object, like most objects, is mutable, it's just that you can't alter *one particular property on it* (that internal slot).

Comment: Thanks for your helpful info! @CertainPerformance

Comment: So you reverted my dupe close so you could answer with a dupe? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35443406/how-to-set-update-the-value-of-a-string-object-in-javascript https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51185/are-javascript-strings-immutable-do-i-need-a-string-builder-in-javascript

Comment: I disagree that string objects are not mutable. They *are*. The data they hold isn't. This seems like a very important difference since OP does not seem to make it.