# How to mutate this in a new String function?

Tags: javascript

I am still getting used to Javascript (I'm coming from C++) and would like to add a new function to String which mutates the string instance directly. Let's say that I want to add a new character at the midpoint of the string (ignoring any error checking). In C++ you could do something like `this->value = ...`. Is that the way to do this in Javascript? TIA

```
String.prototype.mutateSelf = function(param1) {
  // How do I mutate this specific string instance?
  return this;
};
```

Comment: see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51185/are-javascript-strings-immutable-do-i-need-a-string-builder-in-javascript

Comment: You'll almost certainly be returning a *new* string, rather than mutating the instance of the existing string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Javascript strings are immutable. You must construct a new string and return it.