# Hangman game issue

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript and am trying to make a Hangman game. I am at the point where a for loop checks the users input and if it matches, it should replace one of the underscores that is generated. How do I have the user input(ex: a or d) replace one of the underscores? I've tried splicing, and using the .replace method. Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jtpsj5eu/18/

Here is the loop in question:

```js
for (i = 0; i < hangv.input.length; i++) {

  //if user's guess is matched against one of the letters of the word, this will execute. 
  if (guess == hangv.input[i]) {
    //replace underscores with guessed letter 
    newStr = guessa.slice(hangv.input[i], hangv.input[i]) + guess + guessa.slice(hangv.input[i] + 1);
    console.log(newStr);
  } else {
    console.log("false");
  }
}
```

Comment: Try the `substring` method

Comment: It would be easier to use an array, so you can just replace the underscores in place without having to do any slicing or concatenation.

Comment: thanks for suggesting the array. I will try that now

Comment: `string` is immutable in javascript. You cannot replace a character of a `string` once it is instantiated. For more information you can read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4717855/1037569)

Comment: Any ideas on what array methods I should look at for this?