# What is the default value of variable equal to ko.observable()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, knockout.js

I have just started learning KnockoutJS. This is code for folder navigation of webmail client.In the view code, a comparision is made whether the reference variable `$data` and `$root.chosenFolderId()` point to the same memory location. But I don't understand what will be the initial value of `$root.chosenFolderId()`?

[Reference](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=webmail)

### View:

```
<!-- Folders -->
<ul class="folders" data-bind="foreach: folders">
<li data-bind="text: $data, css : {selected: $data == $root.chosenFolderId()}, click: $root.goToFolder"></li>
</ul>
```

### View Model:

```
function WebmailViewModel() {
    // Data
    var self = this;
    self.folders = ['Inbox', 'Archive', 'Sent', 'Spam'];

    self.chosenFolderId = ko.observable();

    //Operations
    self.goToFolder = function(folder){
        self.chosenFolderId(folder);
    };
};

ko.applyBindings(new WebmailViewModel());
```

Comment: Well, what happened when you tried it?

Comment: Initial, no folder is selected but when I click on a folder, it gets selected. Its working but I don't understand how !How does $data == $root.chosenFolderId() matching works ?

Comment: `$data` contains the current item in the iteration on `folders` ("Inbox" for the first iteration) and `$root.chosenFolderId()` contains a `string` that is one of the items in `folders`. There is no "memory location" comparison involved, only simple `string` comparison.

Comment: How will `chosenFolderId` variable know that it has to pick up one of the value from `folders` array ?

Comment: I'm going through this same tutorial, and I have the same question. The answer below doesn't really help me understand what is going on, though.

Answer (score 1):

You're 90% there. As you stated, the foreach will iterate over the `folders` array and `$data` will be the current item in the array.

**Picking up the value for chosenFolderId**

The click binding which calls `goToFolder` will pass the item it was bound to as an argument, so the `chosenFolderId` value will be set to the folder item corresponding to the clicked <li> element.

For example: clicking on the 'Archive' element will fire the click event for the item bound to `folders[1]` thereby calling `goToFolder` with the `folders[1]` value.

**Initial value**

The initial value of `$root.chosenFolderId()` will be `undefined` since you declared it with no argument. On initial view no folders appear selected, if you had:

```
self.folders = ['Inbox', 'Archive', 'Sent', 'Spam'];
self.chosenFolderId = ko.observable(self.folders[0]);
```

then the 'Inbox' would be initially selected.

**Memory location**

You asked if `$data` and `$root.chosenFolderId()` point to the same memory location. That's mostly correct - if your folders were an array of objects then they would contain the same reference (for the selected item). Technically strings are also references in JS (see explanation https://stackoverflow.com/a/51193/625200) but its simpler to think of primitives (strings, numbers, booleans) in JS as values and not references.

Comment: Thanks for the well explained answer! So first the click binding will be applied and then the css binding would work ? Assuming the `foreach` runs infinitely here.

Comment: I'm going through this same tutorial, and I have the same question. The answer here doesn't really help me understand what is going on, though. Is `chosenFolderId` a variable? It is never declared. I searched online to find out what it was, and this is the only place I saw it mentioned. How does Javascript know what to do with it? I'm confused.