# Converting Odd and Even-indexed characters in a string to uppercase/lowercase in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, uppercase, lowercase

I need to make a function that reads a string input and converts the odd indexed characters in the string to upperCase and the even ones to lowerCase.

```
function alternativeCase(string){
    for(var i = 0; i < string.length; i++){
        if (i % 2 != 0) {
            string[i].toUpperCase();
        }
        else {
            string[i].toLowerCase();
        }   
    }
    return string;
}
```

How to fix my code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are JavaScript strings immutable? Do I need a "string builder" in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51185/are-javascript-strings-immutable-do-i-need-a-string-builder-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function alternativeCase(string){
    var output = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < string.length; i++){
        if (i % 2 != 0) {
            output += string[i].toUpperCase();
        }
        else {
            output += string[i].toLowerCase();
         }   
    }
    return output;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me perfectly! I was not that far off with my code!

Comment: nope you werent far off, you were close! As other comments mentioned, strings in JS are "Immutable" which means they can't be changed in memory without assigning it to a new variable (or itself), which is why you couldn't set a character within the string the way you were. That was the only problem with your method.

Answer (score 5):

```
function alternativeCase(string){
  return string.split('').map(function(c,i) {
    return i & 1 ? c.toUpperCase() : c.toLowerCase();
  }).join('');
}
```

---

#### Update 2019

These days it's pretty safe to use ES6 syntax:

```js
const alternativeCase = string => string.split('')
  .map((c,i) => i & 1 ? c.toUpperCase() : c.toLowerCase()).join('');
```

Answer (score 0):

Strings in JavaScript are immutable, Try this instead:

```js
function alternativeCase(string){
     var newString = [];
     for(var i = 0; i < string.length; i++){
        if (i % 2 != 0) {
           newString[i] = string[i].toUpperCase();
        }
        else {
           newString[i] = string[i].toLowerCase();
        }   
     }
   return newString.join('');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

RegExp alternative that handles space between characters :

```js
const alternativeCase = s => s.replace(/(\S\s*)(\S?)/g, (m, a, b) => a.toUpperCase() + b.toLowerCase());

console.log( alternativeCase('alternative Case') )
```