# String assignment behavior in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Does the following result in a memory copy operation?

```
1: var foo, bar;
2: foo = 'abc';
3: bar = foo;
```

Is the memory representation of `foo` copied into the memory pointed at by `bar` on line 3?

Does this change if `foo` is a string 1 MB in size (unlike 6 bytes in this example)?

Finally, is this behavior defined by the ECMAScript specification or left to implementors?

Comment: that is just a reference of a var, so both points to same primitive. So, IMHO there would be one primitive while two vars are having reference to it. I wish i could say it better.

Comment: But strings have pass-by-value semantics which would seem to contradict you.

Comment: @BenAston Where are you observing pass-by-value semantics? JavaScript has "pass-reference-by-value" semantics for non-numeric values - also known as "call by sharing": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing

Comment: OK, so JavaScript has "pass-reference-by-value" semantics for strings - it just doesn't expose a mechanism for changing that value because all "modifier" operations result in a new string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings in JavaScript are immutable and can be considered as "reference types" (a-la Java and C#): [Are JavaScript strings immutable? Do I need a "string builder" in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51185/are-javascript-strings-immutable-do-i-need-a-string-builder-in-javascript)

I had a quick look in the ECMAScript 7 specification but I can't find a single, succinct authoritative reference that simply says "strings are immutable" - you'll have to infer that from the rest of the specification: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html

Regarding the individual questions:

1. No, the contents of the string are not copied on assignment, a reference to the string is.
2. No, if `foo` pointed to a 1MB-sized string then as before, a reference would be passed.
3. See second paragraph.