# If String is immutable in javascript then how splice method changing the original String?

Tags: javascript, string

As i heard, String is immutable in JavaScript then how splice method changing the original String?

As I know
`var name = 'Alto';`// it will create an new object in global space memory with 'alto' and assign to name reference.

`name = 'swift';` // it will create an new object in global space memory and with 'swift' assign to name reference. ('Alto' string object will be moved to garbage collector whenever possible).

`var newName = name.slice(0,2);`// here splicing the 'sw' from 'swift' create an new Object in global space and assign to newName. name will have 'swift' since string is immutable.

`var newName1 = name.splice(0,2);`// here cut the 'sw' from 'swift'(original string) and assign to newName. now name will have 'ift'. so how String is an immutable?

Can anyone explain the process behind splice?

Comment: Immutable? Does that mean it is unable to be changed like a constant?

Comment: `.splice()` is not a method of `String.prototype`

Comment: There's no `splice` method on string. Taking slices of `name` will not change `name`. Perhaps you can write a [MCVE]

Comment: @RobG wrongly typed.now changed the content

Comment: Have you tried `'someString'.splice(1)`? It will throw an error.

Comment: [String Immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4717855/4758494) Here, is another stackoverflow question. This should help you.

Comment: yes. There is no splice method in String.prototype. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

They are immutable. You cannot change a character within a string with something like var myString = "abbdef"; myString[2] = 'c'. The string manipulation methods such as trim, slice return new strings.