# How to make mutation of a string? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mutable, mutation

if objects are mutable by default why in this case it dosen't work?
How to make mutation  value of the key "a" in the object "s"?

```js
var s = {
  a: "my string"
};

s.a[0] = "9"; // mutation
console.log(s.a); // doesn't work
```

Comment: Javscript string are immutable Check this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51185/are-javascript-strings-immutable-do-i-need-a-string-builder-in-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are JavaScript strings immutable? Do I need a "string builder" in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51185/are-javascript-strings-immutable-do-i-need-a-string-builder-in-javascript)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are trying to change a primitive `String`, which is immutable in Javascript.

For exmaple, something like below:

```
var myObject = new String('my value');
var myPrimitive = 'my value';

function myFunc(x) {
  x.mutation = 'my other value';
}

myFunc(myObject);
myFunc(myPrimitive);

console.log('myObject.mutation:', myObject.mutation);
console.log('myPrimitive.mutation:', myPrimitive.mutation);
```

Should output:

```
myObject.mutation: my other value
myPrimitive.mutation: undefined
```

---

But you can define a function in primitive String's prototype, like:

```
String.prototype.replaceAt=function(index, replacement) {
    return this.substr(0, index) + replacement+ this.substr(index + replacement.length);
}

var hello="Hello World"
hello = hello.replaceAt(2, "!!")) //should display He!!o World
```

Or you can just assign another value to s.a, as `s.a = 'Hello World'`

Comment: @JonasW. Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 3):

Strings in JavaScript are immutable. This means that you cannot modify an existing string, you can only create a new string.

```
var test = "first string";
test = "new string"; // same variable now refers to a new string
```

Answer (score 3):

You try to mutate a string which not possible, because strings are immutable. You need an assignment of the new value.

Below a fancy style to change a letter at a given position.

```js
var s = { a: "my string" };

s.a = Object.assign(s.a.split(''), { 0: "9" }).join('');

console.log(s.a);
```

Comment: so can you think of mutable example? 
const egg = { name: "Humpty Dumpty" };
egg.isBroken = false;
console.log(egg);

Comment: pardon, i don't understand.

Comment: const egg mutated in my example?

Comment: `const` means only that you can not assign something to egg, but not to the properties. this is always possible.

Comment: than it is the good example of mutation? Or it's not mutation?

Comment: it is mutation, obvious. but not a good (opinion based) example, just an example.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to mutate the string using element accessor, which is not possible.  If you apply a `'use strict';` to your script, you'll see that it errors out:

```js
'use strict';

var s = {
  a: "my string"
};

s.a[0] = '9';       // mutation
console.log( s.a ); // doesn't work
```

If you want to replace the character of the string, you'll have to use another mechanism.  If you want to see that Objects are mutable, simply do `s.a = '9'` instead and you'll see the value of `a` has been changed.

```js
'use strict';

var s = {
  a: "my string"
};

s.a = s.a.replace(/./,'9')
console.log(s.a);
```