# why we can't modify string length in javascript where as we can modify the length of array?

Tags: javascript

I am learning javascript. In one of the document, I read we can modify the length of array. I tried as below and it worked.

```
var array = new Array(1, 2, 3, 4 ,5);
array.length = 4;
```

Now array becomes [1, 2, 3, 4].

But the same is not working on Strings.

```
var str = new String("abcdef");
str.length = 5;
```

str is not getting modified. Is there any specific reason to not allow this behavior on strings?

Comment: Thanks for all the quick answers.

Comment: In my opinion, the issue comes from the array: setting the array's length directly isn't a very elegant way of mutating an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strings are immutable by design. You can't change them, but you can reassign the reference to a new string value. If you want to shorten a string, you can use the String slice() method.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice

Answer (score 3):

String are immutable. For a new length of the string, you need an assignment wich copies the string with a new length.

```js
var string = 'abcdef';

string = string.slice(0, 4);

console.log(string);
```

Answer (score 2):

.length property is used differently for string, because they are immutable:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length

If you want to alter the length of a string you can create a new string using slice.

Answer (score 1):

When you log your String **object** in the console, you can see why this is not working:

```js
var str = new String("abcdef");
str.length = 5;
console.log(str)
```

Thus, you cannot set the `length` property here. We are talking about the "immutability" of strings in `JavaScript`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length

Comment: Doesn't answer the question. Instead, this is illustrating how to observe the results. The question was on why.

Answer (score 0):

> Attempting to assign a value to a string's .length property has no observable effect.
>
> [MDN Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length)

```js
var myString = "bluebells";

// Attempting to assign a value to a string's .length property has no observable effect. 
myString.length = 4;
console.log(myString);
/* "bluebells" */
```

Comment: In addition to the great quick answers below, you can read a nice explanation about immutable objects here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51185/are-javascript-strings-immutable-do-i-need-a-string-builder-in-javascript

Comment: Thanks for the link @JoshAdams