# In JavaScript, Why constant String cannot be modified but constant array can be modified

Tags: javascript, arrays, constants

```
const name = 1;
name = 2;
```

When executing this JavaScript I get an error :

```
TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/user01/JavaScript/scope.js:2:6)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:612:3
```

But, on executing below statements, code executes successfully.

```
const arr = [1,2,3];
arr[1] = 5;
```

Why are we able to modify an array even if it is declared as constant.

Comment: Because `const` doesn't mean "immutable", unfortunately.

Comment: It's because a const  can't be *reassigned*. You are not reassigning the variable when you change an array. If you don't want `arr` to be mutable you can use `Object.freeze(arr)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the array itself hasn't changed, it is still the same array. In C-like languages an analogue to this would be a constant pointer (to some address in the memory) – you can't change where the pointer points to, but the memory is writable just the same.

In JavaScript, this pointer-like behaviour applies to anything that is not a primitive (i.e. `Number`, `Boolean`, `String` ...), which is basically arrays and objects. If you are wondering why a String is a primitive, it is because [in JavaScript Strings are immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51185/are-javascript-strings-immutable-do-i-need-a-string-builder-in-javascript).

Answer (score 3):

**ES2015** `const` does not indicate that a value is `constant` or `immutable`. A `const` value can definitely change. The following is perfectly valid ES2015 code that does not throw an exception:

```js
const obj = {};
obj.bar = 42;
console.log(obj.bar);
// → 42
```

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3];
arr[1] = 42;
console.log(arr[1]);
// → 42
```

The only thing that’s immutable here is the binding. `const` assigns a value (`{}`) to a variable name (obj) or (`[]`) to a variable name (arr) , and guarantees that no rebinding will happen. Using an `assignment operator` or a `unary` or `postfix` **--** or **++** operator on a `const` variable throws a `TypeError Exception`

So, Any of the following lines will throw an exception.

```
const foo = 27;
foo = 42;
foo *= 42;
foo /= 42;
foo %= 42;
foo += 42;
foo -= 42;
```

Now question is how to make a variable `immutable`?

Primitive values, i.e. `numbers`, `strings`, `booleans`, `symbols`, `null`, or `undefined` are always immutable.

```
var foo = 27;
foo.bar = 42;
console.log(foo.bar);
// → `undefined`
```

To make an **object’s** values `immutable`, use `Object.freeze()`. It has been around since **ES5** and is widely available nowadays.

```
const foo = Object.freeze({
    'bar': 27
});
foo.bar = 42; // throws a TypeError exception in strict mode;
              // silently fails in sloppy mode
console.log(foo.bar);
// → 2
```