# Change first letter of certain words in a string

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to be able to change the first letter of certain words in a string, specifically because I want to capitalise the first and last name of 'john doe'. I have written this code:

```
let name = 'john doe';
name = name.split(' ');
name[0][0] = name[0][0].toUpperCase();
name[1][0] = name[1][0].toUpperCase();
console.log(name.join(' '));
```

However, my code does not execute any change whatsoever.

```
Output:
> "john doe"

Expected output:
> "John Doe"
```

I was wondering what the problem was so I removed `toUpperCase()` and logged each step.

```
let name = 'john doe';
name = name.split(' ');
console.log(name);
console.log(name[0][0]);
name[0][0] = 'p';
console.log(name[0][0]);
```

The output shows that the string was successfully converted into an array. It shows that `name[0][0]` does indeed hold the value 'j'. But it does not change to 'p'.

```
Output: 
> "Array ["john", "doe"]"
> "j"
> "j"

Expected output:
> "Array ["john", "doe"]"
> "j"
> "p"
```

I see no reason why this should not work.

Comment: Strings are immutable

Comment: Is this only for display purposes? If so... `text-transform: capitalize`

Comment: @JonasWilms I removed, calm down! :-D

Comment: *the string was successfully converted into an array* Not really. It just means that the variable no longer points to the string and has been reassigned to point at the array.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51185/are-javascript-strings-immutable-do-i-need-a-string-builder-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strings are immutable. That means that the chars are readonly, trying to set them does actually nothing:

```
 let str = "123";
 str[0] = "2";
 console.log(str); // "123"
```

To modify them, you have to build up a new string composed of the previous string's characters:

```
str = "2" + str.slice(1);
```