# Why isn't my URL string being shortened as expected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a variable named **siteURL** which is set using **window.location.href**.

I'm wanting to trim off the the last 10 characters which in this case is ...index.html.

```
var siteURL = window.location.href;

if (siteURL.endsWith('index.html')) {
   siteURL.substring(0, siteURL.length - 10);
}

//log the output
console.log(siteURL);
```

I'm trying this but it doesn't seem to be removing the last 10 character. Does anyone know where I'm going wrong and could point me in the right direction?

Comment: what does it do?

Comment: JavaScript is case sensitive so you made up a variable name. Also you need to assign the substring to the variable. Strings are primitives and are passed around as copies (not modified in place).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to store the returned value of [String.substring()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring#Syntax) back in `siteUrl` variable. Note also that `strings` are [inmutables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object#JavaScript) on `Javascript` (Check next reference too: [Are JavaScript strings immutable? Do I need a "string builder" in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51185/are-javascript-strings-immutable-do-i-need-a-string-builder-in-javascript)).

```js
var siteURL = "some/url/with/index.html";

if (siteURL.endsWith('index.html'))
{
   siteURL = siteURL.substring(0, siteURL.length - 10);
}

console.log(siteURL);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

However, a better approach for what you want to is to use [String.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with a regular expression:

```js
var siteURL = "some/url/with-index.html/index.html";
siteURL = siteURL.replace(/index\.html$/, "");
console.log(siteURL);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Comment: You're a legend. That's exactly what  I was trying to do. Thanks for including the link to string replace. Super handy!

Answer (score 1):

You're performing the action, you just need to actually assign the value.

`siteURL = siteURL.substring(0, siteURL.length - 10);`

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
var newStr = siteURL.substring(0, siteURL.length-10);

var newStr = siteURL.substr(0, siteURL.length-10);

var newStr = siteURL.slice(0, siteURL.length-10);
```

Any of them  will work:

```
console.log(newStr);
```