# Why doesn't modify each char of a string?

Tags: javascript, string, for-loop

I don't understand why the for loop doesn't modify the chars of a string.
this is

```
function testing (str) {
  let other_str = str
  for (let i = 0; i < other_str.length; i++) {
    other_str[i] = 'g'
  }
  return other_str;
}

console.log(testing('hey'));
```

I am aware that i can use other ways but i want to understand this.

Comment: string are immutable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Strings are immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51185/are-javascript-strings-immutable-do-i-need-a-string-builder-in-javascript) , convert the string to an array, do the modifications and join it back :

```js
function testing(str) {
  let other_str = [...str];
  for (let i = 0; i < other_str.length; i++) {
    other_str[i] = 'g';
  }
  return other_str.join('');
}

console.log(testing('hey'));
```