# toUpperCase not working in for loop when trying to convert to camel case

Tags: javascript

I looked at some other questions, haven't found one specific to this issue. Here is what I have:

```
function toCamelCase(str){
  const _str = str.split(/-|_/)

  for (let i = 0; i < _str.length; i++) {
    // if first character of string is capital,
    // make it Pascal Case, not Camel Case
    if (i === 0) {
      _str[i][0] =
        _str[i][0].match(/[A-Z]/)
          ? _str[i][0].toUpperCase()
          : _str[i][0].toLowerCase()
    } else {
      _str[i][0] = _str[i][0].toUpperCase()
    }
  }

  return _str.join("")
}

toCamelCase("This-is_a_test-string") // Thisisateststring
```

The output should be `ThisIsATestString`, but for some reason it is not working. What's weird is that the first `if (i === 0) ..` enters and assigns properly, but the rest doesn't work, even though it is entered.

Comment: [strings are immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51185/are-javascript-strings-immutable-do-i-need-a-string-builder-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use a replacement with a function for a single letter?

```js
const toCamelCase = string => string.replace(/[_\-](.)/g, (_, g) => g.toUpperCase());

console.log(toCamelCase("This-is_a_test-string"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Strings are **[immutable](https://www.sitepoint.com/immutability-javascript/)** in Javascript. For example.

```
let a = "stackoverflow";

a[0] = a[0].toUpperCase(); // silently ignores 

a; // stackoverflow not Stackoverflow

a = "Stackoverflow";

a; // Stackoverflow; // you can point string to new value
```

In your code you are trying to change string values by using index:

```
str[i][0] = _str[i][0].match(/[A-Z]/) ? _str[i][0].toUpperCase() : _str[i[0].toLowerCase()
```

This won't work cause the immutability of strings in JS.

Instead of that, you can change the whole string.

```js
let a = "This-is_a_test-string";

let temp = a.split(/-|_/).map( (val)=>  val[0].match(/[A-Za-z]/)?  val[0].toUpperCase() + val.split("").slice(1).join("") : val );

console.log(temp.join(""));
```