# How do I insert a hyphen after every 3 characters in a string?

Tags: javascript, string

How do I insert a hyphen after every `3` characters in a string?  Here's what I've tried:

```js
var str = prompt().split("").join(""); // i used split() to convert string to array and join() to remove (,)
var i = 0;
var l = 2;
while (i < str.length) {
  str[l] = "-"; // i think it should puts - every three character but it doesn't 
  l += 3;// i think it should puts - every three character but it doesn't
  i += 1;
};
alert(str);
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on your issue?

Comment: I think they want to add a hyphen between every 3 characters in a string.

Comment: i was expect to put (-) every three letters * just like when you enter a psn card* for example : i enter " 123456789" the output should be : "123-456-789"

Comment: To begin with, ```split()``` will convert the string to an array of chars, the ```join("")``` DOES NOT remove the ```(,)``` if you apply these methods on a string, let's say - ``"Hello, world"`` the result will still be ``"Hello, world"`` Can you elaborate on the issue and also provide us with a demo string and the intended result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To insert a `-` (hyphen) between every 3rd character in a string inputted via `prompt`, use `.replace` with the following `RegExp`:

## `/.{3}(?!$)/g`

This matches every sequence of `3` characters, except for the last.  The `?!` means, unless followed by ... and `$` means the end of the string.

If you replace these triple-character sequences with this:

## `'$&-'`

It will effectively insert a hyphen after, since `$&` is a placeholder for whatever you previously matched.

```js
alert(prompt().replace(/.{3}(?!$)/g, '$&-'));
```

Comment: It also adds an '-' after the last digit.

Comment: Fixed.  Instead of writing `[solved]` you can click the green checkmark on the left of my answer to award me `Best Answer` :)

Comment: How can this be modified to insert a hyphen only ONCE.  Insert it after the first three digits and that's it.  So the end result is something this format:  123-12345

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve with a loop:

```js
const str = '123456789';
let result = "";
let counter = 0;

for(i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
    counter++;
    result += str[i];
    if(counter == 3 && str[i] != str.length){
        result += '-';
        counter = 0;
    }
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: thanks bro it worked , but can you explain why my code didn't please ?

Comment: You are trying to access the index of a string and insert the hypen, but strings are inmutable. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51185/are-javascript-strings-immutable-do-i-need-a-string-builder-in-javascript/4717855

Answer (score 0):

join() function converts array to string, so str[3] doesn't work
You can use  prompt().split("") instead of prompt().split("").join("");

Please look at this code. This will work

```
var str = prompt().split("") ; 
var newstr = "";
var i = 0;

while ( i < str.length){
   newstr +=str[i];
   i += 1;
   if(i % 3 ==0 && i !== str.length)
    newstr += "-";
   
};
alert(newstr);
```

Comment: bro it doesn't work if i replaced number by (l) so it puts - only in the 3rd digit

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
var str = prompt().split("") ; 
var newstr = "";
var i = 0;

while ( i < str.length){
   newstr +=str[i];
   i += 1;
   if(i % 3 ==0 && i !== str.length)
    newstr += "-";
   
};
alert(newstr);
```