# Is there a fast way or function to insert a substring into existing string in Typescript?

Tags: string, typescript, insert, substring

There must be an easy way to do this but I can't figure out how to do so in *Typescript*.

I have the strings:

```
string origin = 'app-home';
string modifier = 'ua-';
```

And I want to end up with a `result` string with the value:

```
console.log(result); // app-ua-home
```

Is there a way to do this easily? `npm` libraries could also be useful.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, [strings are immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51185/438273). However, you could do something like this:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=12&ssc=38&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgUwDYEsC2KoIE4wLwwDkAtIQNwCwAUKJLCmJigIZL5HMAOnxAFiGgTlqtaDAYQcUAGqsArgnaE5zYVWpIEsbAghyksAoTXUAZiFwAKUbDmNYIU+PsskAShgBvajHFPLdpgwAIR4BIioGFjYHjp6BjAA1ASBUJRUvsiSMHH6sMkwAAYAJJ4R6Jg4AL6lElKySAo1ZcgV0VWF6VXUIuAQIJoAdEggAOaWuQZuZDAA9LMwAERcPCp8AgiL1EA)

```ts
const delimiter = '-';
const initial = 'app-home';
const insertValue = 'ua';

let result = '';

for (const unit of initial) {
  if (unit !== delimiter) result += unit;
  else result += `${delimiter}${insertValue}${delimiter}`;
}

console.log(result); // "app-ua-home"
```