# Why is an empty string falsey, but an empty array isn't?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I understand that the answer to this is *it's in the specs* but what, if any, is the logic behind it?

```
Welcome to Node.js v19.0.0.
Type ".help" for more information.
> !!''
false
> !![]
true
```

A `String`, to my understanding, is really an array with some extra functionality added to make text easier to work with, it still does all the array-like things though so why is an empty string `falsey` but an empty array is `truthy`?

Comment: A string is a primitive type and an array is an object. Objects are *always* truthy. That is a simple rule.

Comment: `null` is an object, too. but not *[truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy)*.

Comment: `null` is not an object, but a primitive. It has `typeof` equal to `"object"`, but that is a different story.

Comment: Strings act in a similar way to arrays, but, in javascript at least, they are *not* arrays.   eg you can reference a character with `mystring[0]` but you can't add characters with `mystring.push("end")`.  Note that strings *are* immutable.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51185/are-javascript-strings-immutable-do-i-need-a-string-builder-in-javascript) for more info on strings.

Answer (score -1):

Let's make it simple:

```
!!''
```

An empty string in JavaScript is considered a "falsy" value. It is treated as a boolean false when evaluated in a boolean context.

```
!![]
```

Arrays, whether it contains items or not, are considered "truthy" values in Javascript. They are treated as a boolean true when evaluated in a boolean context.

Comment: This appears to just repeat the question - statement of fact rather than reasons.

Comment: shall I say, *it's by definition* that, objects are truthy, empty strings are falsey? I thought I already mentioned the logic, which is the OP is asking.

Comment: OP isn't asking about the "logic" of true/false, OP is asking about the philosophical *logic* - ie the *reasoning* of *why* it works like this.  OP already stated they know it does work like this.  They key is the phrase "*the logic behind it*"