# Setting nested object property when parent can be undefined?

Tags: javascript

If I want to set a nested property like `foo.bar.baz = true` but it's parent `foo.bar` might be `undefined`, what's the best way to do that?

I know I can do this with:

```
foo.bar = {
  ...foo.bar,
  baz: true
}
```

but is there a more concise way of doing it?

Thanks!

Comment: You could use the nullish coalescing operator  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing and set the default value for the optional parent object (though it s a quite weird pattern)

Comment: Perhaps `foo.bar ??= {}; foo.bar.baz = true;`?  Bit hard to tell what you're after exactly and what you don't like about your current solution? There's also [this](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining-assignment) tc39 stage 1 proposal (but this just skips the assignment if there's no object)

Comment: @NickParsons It's not that I don't like what I already had, just felt like there might be a one-liner out there somewhere.
Useful to know about the coming optional chaining assignment - thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [nullish coalescing assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_assignment) (`??=`)operator:

```js
(foo.bar ??= {}).baz = true;
```

But in my opinion, it's not very readable, and your original code is easier to read. A more readable of the above would be to use:

```js
foo.bar ??= {};
foo.bar.baz = true;
```

This is a bit different to your original code, as it will keep the original object reference in `foo.bar` if it already exists, as opposed to always creating a new one.

Comment: Thanks. I agree sometimes less is not better, but worth checking.

Answer (score 0):

Works as it is:

```js
const foo = {};

foo.bar = {
  ...foo.bar,
  baz: true
};

console.log(foo);
```

Comment: I guess the `?? {}` isn't really needed as when `foo.bar` is `undefined`  (or `null`) the spread `...` will act as a no-op. (this option might make typesript happy though if it doesn't like `...foo.bar`)

Comment: @NickParsons forgot about that, thanks

Comment: No worries - I guess now this is the same as what OP is already doing :( (I think `baz = true` is a typo in their question). (btw, while I have you, not sure if you caught [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51185/are-javascript-strings-immutable-do-i-need-a-string-builder-in-javascript/4717855#comment136023425_4717855), but I noticed something with your benchmarking tool)

Comment: @NickParsons oops, yes typo

Comment: @NickParsons that's for pointing, i will add tests so the previous benchmarks wouldn't fail. there're some new features, i will update the answer with new results in markdown instead of screenshots.

Comment: @NickParsons fixed the benchmark plus updated the answer

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev You have quick fingers, nice work :) !

Answer (score 0):

You could do:
`foo.bar = Object.assign(foo.bar ?? {}, { baz: true })`.

Also I wouldn't consider spread operator used with variables that might be `undefined` as a good practice (although your snippet code won't end up with run time error).

So either way do `foo.bar ?? {}` or `...(foo.bar ?? {})`